# Merge Excel Sheets Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Excel Sheet(Say OG.xls) which has some data already in it with some 5000 rows with headings in the first row and Upto "AN" Columns.
This No of rows(5000) doesn't change for a whole year.
Now i have 5 XL files(Say A,B,C,D,E) and the data from these files has to be appended to this OG file just starting from 5001st row every time.
All these 5 files has different no of columns but identical to that of OG File.
I have to pull data from these files and place them in OG File. 
From File A : Column A,B,C,D,E,F,G&H goes to Column F,G,T,U,V,W,X&Y Of OG.xls File.
Likewise the other files data has to be extracted according to the corresponding column with OG.xls

The second file data has to be appended right below the next row where the File A ends.(Say after filling the data from File A now the OG.xls has 5110 rows,
the File B data has to filled from 5111 st row of OG.xls.
The same follows for the other files too.
The data of these 5 files has to be filled row after row but should match the columns to that of OG.xls

Each time the same operation is repeated by filling the data from 5001st row of OG.xls. For convenience we can have all these files in a same folder.

How can we do this.

Please help me in this!!!
Also let me know for any clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a more presice answer, you would need to try something first and then ask for help in area you have got stuck. My suggestion is you begin by;
1. Start writing a VBA script in OG.XLS, as a first step try to access the file A.xls and reading the columns and pasting them (they can initially be at any location in any order).
2. Once you are able to do this, next step is to see if you put the data in right column (say 5000 in your example) by setting up right kind of variables and using them and incrementing them.
3. Your next step should be to to read the column headings in A.XLS and finding them OG.XLS and identifying them. Initially you can begin by doing a simple string comparision, later you can refine this to do a VLOOKUP.
4. During this process, if you encounter any specific problem, raise it so that you will get a better answer.

Few from the community would go to the extent of writing the entire code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why does Column A end up in Column F, and why does C end up in T? Is there a rule around this such as the first row is a header with with the same text in it?

Maybe a picture might help.

Based on what i can guess, i'd throw each sheet into a RecordSet with meaningful field names (you'll need to reference `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library`) . Once done it will be very easy to append each RecordSet and throw them into a single sheet.

You'll need to be able to find the last column and last row in each sheet to do this cleanly so have a look at [How can i find the last row...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)

**Edit...**

Below is a cleaned up example of how you could do what you need in VBA. The devil is in the details such as empty sheets, and how to handle formulas (this ignores them completely), and how to merge you columns in an appropriate way (again ignored).

This has been tested in Excel 2007.

```
Option Explicit
Const MAX_CHARS = 1200



Sub MergeAllSheets()
  Dim rs As Recordset
  Dim mergedRS As Recordset
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim wb As Workbook

  Dim fieldList As New Collection
  Dim rsetList As New Collection

  Dim f As Variant
  Dim cols As Long
  Dim rows As Long
  Dim c As Long
  Dim r As Long

  Dim ref As String
  Dim fldName As String
  Dim sourceColumn As String



  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
    Set rs = New Recordset
    ref = FindEndCell(sh)
    cols = sh.Range(ref).Column
    rows = sh.Range(ref).Row

    If ref <> "$A$1" Or sh.Range(ref).Value <> "" Then '' This is to catch empty sheet
      c = 1
      r = 1
      Do While c <= cols
        fldName = sh.Cells(r, c).Value
        rs.Fields.Append fldName, adVarChar, MAX_CHARS
        If Not InCollection(fieldList, fldName) Then
          fieldList.Add fldName, fldName
        End If
        c = c + 1
      Loop
      rs.Open


      r = 2
      Do While r <= rows
        rs.AddNew
        c = 1
        Do While c <= cols
          rs.Fields(c - 1) = CStr(sh.Cells(r, c).Value)
          c = c + 1
        Loop
        r = r + 1
        Debug.Print sh.Name & ": " & r & " of " & rows & ", " & c & " of " & cols
      Loop
      rsetList.Add rs, sh.Name
    End If
  Next


  Set mergedRS = New Recordset
  c = 1
  sourceColumn = "SourceSheet"
  Do While InCollection(fieldList, sourceColumn) '' Just in case you merge a merged sheet
    sourceColumn = "SourceSheet" & c
    c = c + 1
  Loop
  mergedRS.Fields.Append sourceColumn, adVarChar, MAX_CHARS
  For Each f In fieldList
    mergedRS.Fields.Append CStr(f), adVarChar, MAX_CHARS
  Next
  mergedRS.Open

  c = 1
  For Each rs In rsetList
    If rs.RecordCount >= 1 Then
      rs.MoveFirst
      Do Until rs.EOF
        mergedRS.AddNew
        mergedRS.Fields(sourceColumn) = "Sheet No. " & c
        For Each f In rs.Fields
          mergedRS.Fields(f.Name) = f.Value
        Next
        rs.MoveNext
      Loop
    End If
    c = c + 1
  Next


  Set sh = wb.Worksheets.Add

  mergedRS.MoveFirst
  r = 1
  c = 1
  For Each f In mergedRS.Fields
    sh.Cells(r, c).Formula = f.Name
    c = c + 1
  Next

  r = 2
  Do Until mergedRS.EOF
    c = 1
    For Each f In mergedRS.Fields
      sh.Cells(r, c).Value = f.Value
      c = c + 1
    Next
    r = r + 1
    mergedRS.MoveNext
  Loop
End Sub

Public Function InCollection(col As Collection, key As String) As Boolean
  Dim var As Variant
  Dim errNumber As Long

  InCollection = False
  Set var = Nothing

  Err.Clear
  On Error Resume Next
    var = col.Item(key)
    errNumber = CLng(Err.Number)
  On Error GoTo 0

  '5 is not in, 0 and 438 represent incollection
  If errNumber = 5 Then ' it is 5 if not in collection
    InCollection = False
  Else
    InCollection = True
  End If

End Function


Public Function FindEndCell(sh As Worksheet) As String
  Dim cols As Long
  Dim rows As Long
  Dim maxCols As Long
  Dim maxRows As Long
  Dim c As Long
  Dim r As Long

  maxRows = sh.rows.Count
  maxCols = sh.Columns.Count

  cols = sh.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
  If cols >= maxCols Then
      cols = 1
  End If


  c = 1
  Do While c <= cols

    r = sh.Cells(1, c).End(xlDown).Row
    If r >= maxRows Then
      r = 1
    End If

    If r > rows Then
      rows = r
    End If
    c = c + 1
  Loop

  FindEndCell = sh.Cells(rows, cols).Address

End Function
```

Comment: Yes it is the identical column headers. The data has to be pasted row-wise but has to be matched according to the column headers. Did i explain clearley?

Comment: Perfect, reading each sheet into a recordset with the first row as your field names should be a breeze. Merging them shouldn't be too hard either. Getting the columns in the right order may be tricky unless you specify it in your first sheet.

Comment: I tried your code Mark but it seems to be missing the function "FindEndCell".  Wont compile.  Is there somewhere I can find this?  I am trying this on Excel 2010.  Thanks!