# Last not empty cell (column) in the given row; Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet in which I need to find the last *non empty cell* in a specific row.

How do I do this?

The below will select this for me, but it will select the *first* not empty cell, I need the last not empty cell in the row #29.

`Worksheets("DTCs").Range("A29").End(xlToRight).Select`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: This is _not_ a duplicate of [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11169445/1026), nor [How can I find last row that contains data in the Excel sheet with a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71180/1026), since this talks about finding the right-most **column**, while those questions are focussed on finding the last **row**, but the general comments and ideas from the answers to those questions apply here as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it might work just search from the other direction, so something like:

```
Worksheets("DTCs").Range("IV29").End(xlToLeft).Select
```

Though maybe the IV would need to be changed to something else depending on the version of Excel (this seems to work in 2003).

Comment: `Worksheets("DTCs").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Select`

Comment: Tim's comment works for all Excel versions and is the superior approach. The only exceptions are when the row is completely empty, or an extreme case where the entire row is filled. Both these situtaions will result with A1, which should trigger a further test to validate the true last used cell.

Comment: Presumably, [like `.End(xlUp)` for rows, this will also fail to handle hidden columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49971540/1026), and a more robust solution would be to get the rightmost column from `UsedRange` and work your way to the left to find the column with data. [My solution  does this to find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49971492/1026) and could be adapted to find the last column as well.

Answer (score 15):

I have expanded on my comment above to provide solutions that

- do not use `Select`
- cater for the last cell in row 1 being used
- cater for the entire row being empty
- cater for the entire row being full

The `Find` method in the second code is a far more direct method of establishing the first non-blank cell

This line `Set rng1 = ws.Rows(1).Find("*", ws.[a1], xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)`
says, start in cell A1 of Sheet "DTCa" then look backwards (ie from the last cell in row 1) in row1 by column looking for anything (the `*`). This method either find the last non blank or returns `Nothing` , ie an empty row

*using `xltoLeft` with specific checks*

```
Sub Method1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws = Sheets("DTCs")
If ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count) = vbNullString Then
    Set rng1 = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    If rng1.Column <> 1 Then
        'return last used cell
        MsgBox "rng1 contains " & rng1.Address(0, 0)
    Else
    If ws.[a1] = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox ws.Name & " row1 is completely empty", vbCritical
        Else
            'true last used cell is A1
            MsgBox "rng1 contains " & rng1.Address(0, 0)
        End If
    End If
Else
    'last cell is non-blank
    MsgBox ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count) & " contains a value", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

*recommended*

```
Sub Method2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("DTCs")
    Set rng1 = ws.Rows(1).Find("*", ws.[a1], xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "rng1 contains " & rng1.Address(0, 0)
    Else
        MsgBox ws.Name & " row1 is completely empty", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that compaisons like `ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count) = vbNullString` will raise an error if the cell contains an error value like `#N/A`. Also note that the `.Find` call changes the defaults in the Excel's Find dialog, which is why I avoid using it. See [the list of gotchas like these I've compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49971540/1026).

Comment: When row number changed it says typemismatch.. can you where do i need to change for different rows