# Excel VBA: Get Last Cell Containing Data within Selected Range

Tags: vba, excel

How do I use Excel VBA to get the last cell that contains data within a specific range, such as in columns A and B `Range("A:B")`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8583926/641067

Comment: This question has been asked a thousand times.  See this link:  [Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelRanges.htm)

Answer (score 8):

using `Find` like below is useful as it

- can find the last (or first) cell in a 2D range immediately
- testing for `Nothing` identifies a blank range
- will work on a range that may not be contiguous (ie a `SpecialCells` range)

change `"YourSheet"` to the name of the sheet you are searching

```
Sub Method2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("YourSheet")
    Set rng1 = ws.Columns("A:B").Find("*", ws.[a1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "last cell is " & rng1.Address(0, 0)
    Else
        MsgBox ws.Name & " columns A:B are empty", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Find` is indeed also worth noting even if this is not my favorite way :)

Comment: For more the one column/row - find is the best method IMHO. :) +1

Answer (score 6):

You can try several ways:

### Using xlUp

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastCellA As Range, LastCellB As Range
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With WS
    Set LastCellA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    Set LastCellB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(LastCellA.Row, LastCellB.Row)
End With
```

### Using SpecialCells

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastCell As Range
Set LastCell = Range("A:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
```

The latter can sometimes be tricky and might not work as you wanted it to.

### More tips

You can also have a look at [Chip Pearson's page about this issue](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/LastCell.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For a variable selection you can use

```
Sub test()
    Dim arrArray As Variant
    Dim iAct As Integer
    Dim iHighest As Integer
    arrArray = Split(Selection.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1), ":")
    For Count = Right(arrArray(0), 1) To Right(arrArray(1), 1)
        iAct = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If iAct > iHighest Then iHighest = iAct
    Next Count
    MsgBox iHighest
End Sub
```

Comment: For `Range("A:B")` just replace `Selection`

Comment: Sorry, but looping to find the last cell, is just a waste of time and resources IMHO.