# How to get the value of the last non-empty cell in a row?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Here is a sample spreadsheet

[image: Sample table]

I want to select a range (ex: `A2:E2`) and get the value `1`. If I select `A4:E4` I will get the value `1`; and so on. Is there any way to achieve this with a macro?

Another thing I would need is the value in the first row of the corresponding column. Ex:

If I select `A2:E2`  I want to get `n` (since 1 is in column E), if I select `A4:E4` I want to get `v` (since 1 is in column C).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Last not empty cell in row; Excel VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872512/last-not-empty-cell-in-row-excel-vb).

Comment: Yeah, this is such a multiple duplicate. And there are tons of questions about getting the last non-empty cell in a column, too -- and the answer is practically the same. @user1112251, you gotta start using the search function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a function which you can use as a formula in the workbook. It also addresses **both** your questions. :)

Paste the below code in a module.

**SYNTAX/USAGE**

**=MyFunc(Cell Range, Arg)**

**Cell Range**: (Required) A range such as A2:E2

**Arg**: (Required) Can take a value of "H" Or "R". "H" will give you the column Header and "R" will give you the row value

**Example**

=MyFunc(A1:E2,"H") will give you "n" AND

=MyFunc(A1:E2,"R") will give you "1"

```
Option Explicit

Function MyFunc(rng As Range, stype As String) As Variant
    Dim MyArray() As String
    Dim sCol As Long

    If stype = "" Or (UCase(stype) <> "H" And _
    UCase(stype) <> "R") Then Exit Function

    With rng
        MyArray = Split(.Address, "$")

        sCol = Cells(Val(MyArray(UBound(MyArray))), _
        Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        If UCase(stype) = "H" Then
            MyFunc = Cells(1, sCol)
        ElseIf UCase(stype) = "R" Then
            MyFunc = Range(MyArray(UBound(MyArray) - 1) & _
            MyArray(UBound(MyArray))).Value
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Note: This is just a general code to show you how it works and it doesn't handle any errors at the moment.

Comment: You solution is great, but when I use "H" to get the headers, It only returns 0.

Comment: I had tried the code before posting. Hope you are not entering the formula in the same row as the data. For example, if I take the above example then you cannot put the formula anywhere in Rows 1-5. Of Course this can be taken care of with few more lines in the above code

Answer (score 2):

The following code should do what you want.  Note: I am not selecting anything since this slows things down to no advantage.

```
Dim ColLast as Long
Dim ValueColLast as String
Dim HeadColLast as String

With Sheets(xxxxx)

  ColLast = .Cells(2,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  ValueColLast = .Cells(2, ColLast).Value
  HeadColLast = .Cells(1,ColLast).Value 

End With
```

`Cells(Row, Column)` addresses the cell identified by Row and Column in the active worksheet.  Row must be a number.  Column can be a number (eg 1 or 104) or a column identifier (eg "A" or "CZ")

`.Cells(Row, Column)` addresses the cell identified by Row and Column in the worksheet identified in the With statement.  Note the leading dot.

`.Cells(2,Columns.Count)` addresses the last cell in row 2 since `Columns.Count` given the number of columns per worksheet for the current version of Excel.  `` `Rows.Count `` does the same for rows.

Assuming `.Cells(2,Columns.Count)` is blank, `.Cells(2,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)` finds the next cell in the specified direction with a value.  This is the VBA equivalent of Ctrl+LeftArrow.  `xlToRight`, `xlUp` and `xlDown` allow you to move in the other directions. `.Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp)` gives the last used row in Column A.

`.Cells(2,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` gives the number of the last used column in row 2.

`ValueColLast = .Cells(2, ColLast).Value` sets ValueColLast to the value of the last cell in Row 2.  I have defined ValueColLast as a String because, if I assumed it was a number and defined it as Long, I would get an error if it was not.

`HeadColLast = .Cells(1,ColLast).Value` sets HeadColLast to value in Row 1.

Hope this all makes sense.

Comment: You might explain your code with inline comments, to avoid having a cluttered answer. Also, if you don't select anything how will your code know what values to return?

Comment: @JP.  I assume (perhaps unfairly) the OP has little knowledge of the syntax so wanted to provide a detailed explanation.  I will use inline comments to explain why I am doing something but not to explain the syntax.  Perhaps I was unclear; I should have said I was not selecting worksheets or ranges or cells as in no `Range(X).Select` `Value = ActiveCell.Value`.

Comment: Using the arrow key shortcuts to determine range limits does rqeuire two tests for completeness a) testing that cell used to start the search from is empty [uncommon as this would normally mean the entire row/column if full] b) testing that the cell found is not empty [more common as rows and columns are often completely empty]. The `Find` approach in the link I posted gets around this checking process

Comment: @brettdj. _I cannot get my responses to brettdj and JP in anywhere close to 500 characters so two comments that need to be read as one_. I find I learn best if I have to struggle with a problem. Whether I find or am given the solution, I will remember it and a bit more which guides my approach to answering questions: the solution and a bit more. But this approach breaks down when finding the last used cell in a range because every technique (find, arrow key shortcuts, special cells) fails in one or more situations.

Comment: @JP. Do I explain the solution or when it might fail because to do both seems too much? Here I gave an over-the-top explanation of the arrow key shortcut approach and ignored failure conditions. Wrong? Probably in this case? For my own use I have a workbook with some 20 worksheets each of which exhibits a different boundary condition and a routine that works for all of them. I have learnt a lot about boundary conditions since I wrote that routine. Perhaps I should review it and publish it.