# Get row number of lowest/largest row number containing data?

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find last row that contains data in the excel sheet with a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)
>   [Error Finding Last Used cell In VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

If I have a spreadsheet and the largest row number which has data is 10,434 is there a function which will give me the row number 10,434?

Thank you

Comment: That question doesn't look related- unless i am after usedrange?

Comment: Are you looking for the last row which has data?

Comment: @Remou: That is an incorrect way of finding the lastrow.

Comment: The duplicate posted is also a duplicate and therefore an incorrect reference.

Comment: @Remou: Yes the duplicate posted is a duplicate but gives you the complete answer unlike the original :)

Comment: I think you will find there are two parts to the reference I posted.

Comment: @Remou: Yup. I saw that and the second is incorrect as well.

Comment: I was hoping there was an inbuilt vba function- rather than assuming 65536 rows etc (and as i'm on Excel 2007 that would definitely not work)

Comment: @Porcupine: Did you see my answer in the link that I gave? That will work in any version of Excel

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8583926/641067

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub largestrow()
Dim largestrowNum As Long
Dim col As Integer
For col = 1 To Columns.Count
lastrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Cells(65536, col).End(xlUp).Row, largestrowNum)
Next col
MsgBox "Largest row number =" & largestrowNum
End Sub
```

(will work as long as you have less than 65536 rows)

Comment: This code uses the 65536 row limit of xl2003. A more robust version is `Cells(Rows.Count, col)`. But this still fails in this example for a blank column