# Opening a workbook with VBA/macro is making it read only?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like my code to open a workbook (always the same one), detect the first free row, write to just two cells in that row, and then save/close the workbook. This seems like a simple problem, but the macro seems to be opening a copy of the file, and then locking it for editing.

Can you see any errors in my open code? I know that the file opens and that the row search works, but then it 1. never writes to the cells, and 2. locks the file.

```
Function WriteToMaster(Num, Path) As Boolean

'Declare variables
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim infoLoc As Long

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

'Specifies where the Master Move Key is stored
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("DOC LOCATION")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Loop through cells, looking for an empty one, and set that to the loan number
infoLoc = firstBlankRow(ws)
MsgBox "First blank row is " & infoLoc & ". Num is " & Num

ws.Cells(infoLoc, 1).Value = Num
ws.Cells(infoLoc, 2).Value = Path


'Save, close, and quit
wb.Save
wb.Close
xlApp.Quit

'Resets the variables
Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

'pieces of function from http://p2p.wrox.com/vb-how/30-read-write-excel-file-using-vb6.html
End Function
```

Thank you again, stackoverflow <3

Comment: do you get any error messages?

Comment: does the workbook open as readonly when you do it manually?

Comment: For future reference, the function [firstBlankRow comes from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497804/finding-first-blank-row-then-writing-to-it/)

Comment: @SeanCheshire No it doesn't throw any errors, and I can make it write correctly to the current wkbk, which makes me think it's an error with the new workbook portion (and not the writing portion).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Not that I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to open a new excel app just to open a workbook?

Can't you just do something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim wkb As Workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\User Documents$\bob\My Documents\workbook_open_example.xlsx"
Set wkb = Workbooks("workbook_open_example.xlsx")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved half of my problem, and I think the other half was caused by a corrupted file of some sort...I restarted my computer and replaced my master file, and now the macro works as intended. I really appreciate it!