# How to determine the last Row used in VBA including blank spaces in between

Tags: excel, vba

How can I determine the last row in an Excel sheet, including some blank lines in the middle?

With this function:

```
Function ultimaFilaBlanco(col As String) As Long        
        Dim lastRow As Long
        With ActiveSheet
            lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row
        End With            
        ultimaFilaBlanco = lastRow          
End Function
```

And this data:

```
Row 1 : Value
Row 2 : Value
Row 3 : Value
Row 4 : Value
Row 5 : Value
Row 6 : White
Row 7 : Value
Row 8 : Value
Row 9 : Value
Row 10  : White
Row 11  : White
Row 12  : White
Row 13  : Value
Row 14  : White
```

The function returns 5, and I need 13. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Duplicate of [Last not empty cell in row; Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872512/last-not-empty-cell-in-row-excel-vba)

Comment: Be careful, the `UsedRange.Rows.Count` returns the number of rows used **ever**. If you use
100 rows and then `clearcontents` the `UsedRange.Row.Count` still returns 100.

Comment: See my post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro/46419169#46419169 I think it can solve your request.

Comment: Strangely enough, I'm running the following code and it works even with blank rows in between: `ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row` 
_(Excel 2016 on MacOS X)_

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're really close. Try using a large row number with `End(xlUp)`

```
Function ultimaFilaBlanco(col As String) As Long

        Dim lastRow As Long
        With ActiveSheet
            lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, col).End(xlUp).row
        End With

        ultimaFilaBlanco = lastRow

End Function
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Im testing, Do you know why I have to return a variant and not a long?

Comment: Check @JHK answer for improvement.

Answer (score 60):

The best way to get number of last row used is:

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` for the **current sheet**.

`Worksheets("Sheet name").UsedRange.Rows.Count` for a **specific sheet**.

To get number of the last column used:

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count` for the **current sheet**.

`Worksheets("Sheet name").UsedRange.Columns.Count` for a **specific sheet**.

I hope this helps.

Abdo

Comment: Thanks. This works FASTER as I know. I'd accept this as answer.

Comment: This only works if the first non-blank row is row 1.

Comment: If you want to get the last row in the used range, do it properly -- see [manuel's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20745570/1026). Read [sancho.s answer to know what this returns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637752/1026) and if you need a row that has data (and not some left-over formatting) and/or in a specific column, check out [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49971492/1026).

Answer (score 27):

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row -1
```

Short. Safe. Fast. Will return the last non-empty row even if there are blank lines on top of the sheet, or anywhere else. Works also for an empty sheet (Excel reports 1 used row on an empty sheet so the expression will be 1). Tested and working on Excel 2002 and Excel 2010.

Comment: This surely has to be the most accurate answer.  The Count answers assume you are starting from the first row (ie 1) - there are occasions where you are not.  This gives you the actual row index the range ends on. I would accept this as the answer.

Comment: @manuel your statement did the job perfectly for starting blank rows, can u elaborate it a little

Comment: While this is the correct way to get the last row of the `UsedRange`, it's important to understand [what it is (and isn't)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637752/1026).

Answer (score 18):

I use the following:

```
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

It'll find the last row in a specific column. If you want the last used row for *any* column then:

```
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Comment: More reliable... Works fine even with `ClearContents` or removing duplicates

Answer (score 4):

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Comment: That function made exactly the same that my function.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [an answer that was posted later but gathered many more upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17067939/1026) and shares the same problems, namely it returns the number of rows in the UsedRange, not the [last row number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20745570/1026), it also doesn't mention [what the UsedRange is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637752/1026).

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is the "as string" in your function. Replace it with "as double" or "as long" to make it work. This way it even works if the last row is bigger than the "large number" proposed in the accepted answer.

So this should work

```
Function ultimaFilaBlanco(col As double) As Long        
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row
    End With            
    ultimaFilaBlanco = lastRow          
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

If sheet contains unused area on the top, `UsedRange.Rows.Count` is not the maximum row.

This is the correct max row number.

```
maxrow = Sheets("..name..").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("..name..").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
```

Answer (score 1):

Well apart from all mentioned ones, there are several other ways to find the last row or column in a worksheet or specified range.

```
Function FindingLastRow(col As String) As Long

  'PURPOSE: Various ways to find the last row in a column or a range
  'ASSUMPTION: col is passed as column header name in string data type i.e. "B", "AZ" etc.

   Dim wks As Worksheet
   Dim lstRow As Long

   Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Please change the sheet name
   'Set wks = ActiveSheet   'or for your problem uncomment this line

   'Method #1: By Finding Last used cell in the worksheet
   lstRow = wks.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

   'Method #2: Using Table Range
   lstRow = wks.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

   'Method #3 : Manual way of selecting last Row : Ctrl + Shift + End
   lstRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

   'Method #4: By using UsedRange
   wks.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
   lstRow = wks.UsedRange.Rows(wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

   'Method #5: Using Named Range
   lstRow = wks.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

   'Method #6: Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be the first cell in data set)
   lstRow = wks.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

   'Method #7: Using Range.Find method
   lstRow = wks.Column(col).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

   FindingLastRow = lstRow

End Function
```

**Note**: Please use only one of the above method as it justifies your problem statement.

Please pay attention to the fact that *Find method does not see cell formatting* but only data, hence look for xlCellTypeLastCell if only data is important and not formatting. Also, *merged cells (which must be avoided) might give you unexpected results* as it will give you the row number of the first cell and not the last cell in the merged cells.

Comment: In [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49971540/1026) I list the gotchas with most of these approaches...

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count).row
```

ActiveSheet can be replaced with `WorkSheets(1)` or `WorkSheets("name here")`

Answer (score -1):

here is my code to find the next empty row for example in first row 'A'.
To use it for any other row just change cells(i,2 or 3 or 4 so on)

```
Sheets("Sheeet1").Select
   for i=1 to 5000
        if cells(i,1)="" then nextEmpty=i goto 20
   next i
20 'continue your code here 

enter code here
```

Answer (score -1):

Better:

```
if cells(i,1)="" then 
nextEmpty=i: 
exit for
```

Comment: Bit late to the party.... although I agree that `Exit For` would be better than `GoTo 20` - I assume you're responding to the answer given by @OdiljonJakhangirov.  But - code for `Ctrl+Up` is faster as is the `Find` method.