# export text file excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a commandbutton that exports my table to a tab separated text file and add some dynamic headers to it.
I want the headers to say:
1/x 2/x 3/x 4/x and so forth where x being the total amount of columns

This is my code so far that I got from a website:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As   Integer

    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\projekt.txt"

    Set rng = Selection

    Open myFile For Output As #1

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

            cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

            If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
                Write #1, cellValue
            Else
                Write #1, cellValue,
            End If

        Next j
    Next i

    Close #1
End Sub
```

The problem is this depends on me marking the filled cells for it to work,
also it only produces comma separated text files, I want tab separated files without "". Also it doesnt produce headers.

```
1/5    2/5    3/5    4/5    5/5
x(total) rows
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data
```

Comment: Could you post what you want the output to look like?

Comment: I have added that, thanx for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only outputs selected cells because in your code you have at line 4

```
Set rng = Selection
```

If you want to export always a specific range, example A1:E100, you can change this line to,

```
Set rng = Range("A1:E100")
```

If this range include the headers, then your export will also have headers.

Second problem,

It is comma separated because you have

```
Write #1, cellValue,
```

To make it tab demilited, change this line to

```
Write #1, cellValue & vbTab
```

---

this should be the complete code for the write section, `vbNewline` implies the "new line" character (or `vbCrLf` also can), `vbTab` is the tab character

```
If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    Write #1, cellValue & vbNewLine
Else
    Write #1, cellValue & vbTab
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I wonder is there anyway I dont need to specify the range, I mean that it only exports the columns and rows that are used, I mean if my table has 10 rows and 15 columns that it will only export those cells.

Comment: @Heresh you certainly can. Try research this **[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686801/how-to-determine-the-last-row-used-in-vba-including-blank-spaces-in-between)** on how to determine last row. it works the same for column.

Comment: after having the last row, you can then write the code like `Set rng = Range("A1:E" & LastRow)` where `LastRow` is the variable assign with the last row value.

Comment: Thanks I surely will look into that and figure that one out.

Comment: But your other comment on how to make it tab separated didnt work for me, I got every column on a new row instead.

Comment: ya i see that now, thanks for pointing that out, pls see my updated answer

Comment: I still get the columns on different lines, not separated by tabs.

Comment: i think each `Write` creates a new line, so perhaps need to change the code such that when you `Write` a `CellValue`, the Cellvalue is already the entire line string with vbTab as delimeter. i am some how busy lately, its not difficult to change the code, try urself first... i'll come back and update the answer