# Copy and paste a range of cells where the range changes each time the data is refreshed

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet where data is refreshed each day. I want to copy and paste the data into an archive sheet. I have managed to do this with selecting a specific range of cells but the issue is that the range of cells will change each day.

```
Sub Archive_Data()

Dim mainworkbook As Workbook
Set mainworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
mainworkbook.Sheets("Status Report (Execution)").Range("B17:AB56").Copy
mainworkbook.Sheets("Archive  Execution").Paste

End Sub
```

This code selects all of the data and pastes it but it is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Help us to help you.  **Post your current code**.

Comment: What causes the range of cells to change ?

Comment: Sub Archive_Data()

Dim mainworkbook As Workbook
Set mainworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
mainworkbook.Sheets("Status Report (Execution)").Range("B17:AB56").Copy
mainworkbook.Sheets("Archive  Execution").Paste
    


End Sub

Comment: This is my current code, I have little experience using VBA and realise that there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Lets summarize - your problem is that you have to locate the last column and the last row of your range, because these are changing daily. Once you have these, you have your range.

Here you can get some ideas for locating the last row.
[How to determine the last Row used in VBA including blank spaces in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686801/how-to-determine-the-last-row-used-in-vba-including-blank-spaces-in-between)

The logic for the last column is really similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a named range.  (Highlight range of cells, right-click, Define name...)  If rows or columns are added within the range, the range boundaries are automatically updated.
Then, in your code,

```
Dim rangeName
rangeName = "Status Report"  'Or whatever name you gave the range.            
Application.Goto Reference:=rangeName 'This will also select the range of cells.
selection.Copy
mainworkbook.Sheets("Archive  Execution").Paste
```

You can also create a named range for the destination if you want to put the copied cells in a specific location on the target page.  Here are some subroutines that may help you.

```
Public Sub test()
    Call Copy_Detail_Rows("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Status_Report")
End Sub

Private Sub Copy_Detail_Rows(sourceWorksheet, targetWorksheet, rangeName)
    '
    ' Copy_Detail_Rows Macro
    ' Copy the detail rows using rangeName from the source worksheet to the target worksheet.
    ' See Formulas tab, Name Manager to manage named ranges.
    '
        'First, check to ensure that the source and target worksheets exist.
        On Error GoTo SourceWorksheetErrorHandler
            Sheets(sourceWorksheet).Select  'Go to the source worksheet.
        On Error GoTo 0 'Reset default error handling.

        On Error GoTo TargetWorksheetErrorHandler
            Sheets(targetWorksheet).Select  'Go to the target worksheet.
        On Error GoTo 0 'Reset default error handling.

        'Delete any existing data in the target range.
        On Error GoTo TargetReferenceErrorHandler
            Application.Goto Reference:=rangeName 'This will also select the range of cells.
        On Error GoTo 0 'Reset default error handling.
        selection.ClearContents 'Cannot use Selection.Delete because it will wipe out the rangeName.

        Sheets(sourceWorksheet).Select  'Go to the source worksheet.
        On Error GoTo SourceReferenceErrorHandler
            Application.Goto Reference:=rangeName 'This will also select the range of cells.
        On Error GoTo 0 'Reset default error handling.
        selection.Copy
        Sheets(targetWorksheet).Select  'Go to the target worksheet.

        On Error GoTo TargetReferenceErrorHandler
            Application.Goto Reference:=rangeName 'This will also select the range of cells.
        On Error GoTo 0 'Reset default error handling.

        selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Exit Sub 'Skip the error handlers below.

    SourceWorksheetErrorHandler:
        On Error GoTo 0 'Reset default error handling.
        Call WorksheetErrorHandlerMessage(sourceWorksheet, "copied from")
        Err.Raise 1001, "Module1::Copy_Detail_Rows()", "Unable to locate the source worksheet."
        'Uncomment one of the following lines as needed.
        'Resume 0 'Resumes with line that caused the error.
        'Resume Next 'Resumes with line following the line which caused the error.
        'Resume <line number or label> 'Resumes with line number or label provided.
        Exit Sub

    TargetWorksheetErrorHandler:
        On Error GoTo 0 'Reset default error handling.
        Call WorksheetErrorHandlerMessage(targetWorksheet, "copied to")
        Err.Raise 1002, "Module1::Copy_Detail_Rows()", "Unable to locate the target worksheet."
        Exit Sub

    SourceReferenceErrorHandler:
        On Error GoTo 0 'Reset default error handling.
        Call ReferenceErrorHandlerMessage(sourceWorksheet, rangeName, "copied from")
        Err.Raise 1003, "Module1::Copy_Detail_Rows()", "Unable to locate the source range."
        Exit Sub

    TargetReferenceErrorHandler:
        On Error GoTo 0 'Reset default error handling.
        Call ReferenceErrorHandlerMessage(targetWorksheet, rangeName, "copied to")
        Err.Raise 1004, "Module1::Copy_Detail_Rows()", "Unable to locate the target range."
        Exit Sub

    End Sub

    Private Sub WorksheetErrorHandlerMessage(worksheetName, operation)
        MsgBox ("Cannot locate the worksheet: " & worksheetName & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                 & "Please select the worksheet where you want the detail rows " & operation _
                 & " and name it: " & worksheetName & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                 & "Select the range of cells to be used for copy operation and run the macro, " _
                 & "Create_Range_Name_For_Current_Selection." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                 & "Then you can re-run this macro.  (Press Alt-F8 to view the macro menu.)" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                 & "Note: The range selection on the source worksheet can be multiple groups of cells, " _
                 & "but the destination range on the target should be a single cell or row." _
                 )
    End Sub


    Private Sub ReferenceErrorHandlerMessage(worksheetName, rangeName, operation)
        MsgBox ("Cannot locate the range: " & rangeName & " on sheet: " & worksheetName & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                 & "Please select the cell(s) where you want the detail rows " & operation & " and run the macro, " _
                 & "Create_Range_Name_For_Current_Selection." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                 & "Then you can re-run this macro.  (Press Alt-F8 to view the macro menu.)" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                 & "Note: The range selection can be multiple groups of cells." _
                 )
    End Sub


    Private Sub ShowSelectionAttributes()
        'If the selection is not contiguous, the row count and column count are from the first block of cells.
        MsgBox ("Current selection: " & vbCrLf _
                & "   Address = " & selection.address() & vbCrLf _
                & "   AddressLocal = " & selection.AddressLocal() & vbCrLf _
                & "   Cells.Count = " & selection.Cells.Count() & vbCrLf _
                & "   Rows.Count = " & selection.Rows.Count() & vbCrLf _
                & "   Columns.Count = " & selection.Columns.Count() & vbCrLf _
                & "   First row number = " & selection.row & vbCrLf _
                & "   Last row number (calculated) = " & (selection.Rows.Count() + selection.row - 1) & vbCrLf _
                & "   Last row number (from range) = " & Get_Last_Row_Number_From(selection) & vbCrLf _
                & "   ActiveSheet.Name = " & ActiveSheet.Name() _
                )
    End Sub

    Sub Create_Range_Name_For_Current_Selection()
    '
    ' Create the named range based on the current cell selection.
    ' This does not need to be a contiguous group of cells - it can be
    ' multiple groups of cells anywhere on the page.

        Dim rangeName
        rangeName = "Status_Report" 'Consider using a global variable for this.
        'Call ShowSelectionAttributes   'Displays a message box.  Uncomment this if you want to see some of the attributes.
        On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Names(rangeName).Delete 'This just deletes the name, not the data in the range.
        On Error GoTo 0 'Reset error handler.
        'The RefersTo targetWorksheet name needs to be enclosed in single quotes in case it contains spaces.
        ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:=rangeName, _
            RefersTo:="='" & ActiveSheet.Name() & "'!" & selection.address()
        'Use the RefersTo format above to pass Row and Column names e.g. "$A$7:$L$340"  (Note $ is absolute - w/o $ is relative)
        'Use the RefersToR1C1 format below to pass Row and Column number (default format when recording a macro).
        'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro_Test").Names.Add Name:="Status_Report_Detail_Rows", _
        '    RefersToR1C1:="=Macro_Test!R7C1:R340C12"

    End Sub
    Function Get_Column_Number_For(aColumnName)
        'Utility function for converting column names to the corresponding numbers.
        'In the Immediate window, ?Get_Column_Number_For("AZ") should return 52.
        Get_Column_Number_For = Range(aColumnName & 1).Column 'Get column number from the cell at aColumnName and row number 1.
    End Function

    Function Get_Column_Name_For(aColumnNumber)
        'Return the column name (letter(s)) corresponding to this column number.
        'Use the cell at row 1, aColumnNumber to get the column name.
        'In the Immediate window, ?Get_Column_Name_For(52) should return AZ.
        Get_Column_Name_For = Get_First_Column_Name_From(Cells(1, aColumnNumber))
    End Function

    Function Get_First_Column_Name_From(aRange)
        'Return the column name (letter(s)) from the first cell in aRange.
        'The range does not need to be contiguous.  It can also be a single cell.  Note that the first
        'cell in a range may not be the furthest cell to the left.  Cells selected by using the Ctrl key
        'are listed in the order of selection.
        'Get the column name for the current selection by calling Get_First_Column_Name_From(selection)
        Get_First_Column_Name_From = Get_First_Column_Name_From_Address(Cells(aRange.row, aRange.Column).address)
    End Function

    Function Get_First_Column_Name_From_Address(aRangeAddress)
        Get_First_Column_Name_From_Address = Split(aRangeAddress, "$")(1) 'Get the first element of the array.
    End Function

    Function Get_Last_Column_Name_From(aRange)
        Get_Last_Column_Name_From = Get_Last_Column_Name_From_Address(aRange.address)
    End Function

    Function Get_Last_Column_Name_From_Address(aRangeAddress)
        'Return the column name (letter(s)) from the last cell in aRange.
        'The range does not need to be contiguous.  It can also be a single cell.  Note that the last
        'cell in a range may not be the furthest cell to the right.  Cells selected by using the Ctrl key
        'are listed in the order of selection.
        'Get the column name for the current selection by calling Get_Last_Column_Name_From(selection)

        Dim rangeArray() As String
        Dim rangeCount As Integer
        Dim lastRangeGroup As String
        Dim lastCellAddress As String

        rangeArray = Split(aRangeAddress, ",") 'aRange can contain multiple groups separated by commas.
        rangeCount = UBound(rangeArray)
        lastRangeGroup = rangeArray(rangeCount)
        rangeArray = Split(lastRangeGroup, ":") 'Split the last group on the colon (:) if it exists.
        rangeCount = UBound(rangeArray)
        lastCellAddress = rangeArray(rangeCount)

        Get_Last_Column_Name_From_Address = Split(lastCellAddress, "$")(1) 'Get the first element of the array.
    End Function

    Function Get_First_Row_Number_From(aRange)
        'Returns the row number as a string.
        Get_First_Row_Number_From = aRange.row
    End Function

    Function Get_Last_Row_Number_From(aRange)
        'Returns the row number as a string.
        Get_Last_Row_Number_From = Get_Last_Row_Number_From_Address(aRange.address)
    End Function

    Function Get_Last_Row_Number_From_Address(aRangeAddress)
        'Returns the row number as a string.
        'We can't just add the first row to the row count because the range may not be contiguous.
        'If the selection is not contiguous, the row count and column count are from the first block of cells.
        'See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195745(v=office.15).aspx for info on Areas.Count.
        'Return the number from the last cell in aRange.
        'The range does not need to be contiguous.  It can also be a single cell.  Note that the last
        'cell in a range may not be the furthest cell to the bottom/right.  Cells selected by using the Ctrl key
        'are listed in the order of selection.
        'Get the last row number for the current selection by calling Get_Last_Row_Number_From(selection)

        Dim rangeArray() As String
        Dim rangeCount As Integer
        Dim lastRangeGroup As String
        Dim lastCellAddress As String

        rangeArray = Split(aRangeAddress, ",") 'aRange can contain multiple groups separated by commas.
        rangeCount = UBound(rangeArray)
        lastRangeGroup = rangeArray(rangeCount)
        rangeArray = Split(lastRangeGroup, ":") 'Split the last group on the colon (:) if it exists.
        rangeCount = UBound(rangeArray)
        lastCellAddress = rangeArray(rangeCount)

        Get_Last_Row_Number_From_Address = Split(lastCellAddress, "$")(2) 'Get the second element of the array.
                                                                          'Note: It's really the third element because
                                                                          'there are two $ signs and it's a zero-based index.
    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using the first set of code you supplied, I am receiving run time error '424' object required? Do you know why?

Comment: Update - I have fixed this issue but I am now getting run time error 9 subscript out of range

Comment: Sorry for the late response...  I noticed that there is a reference to a Get_Last_Row_Number_From(selection) function which is missing from the code that I gave you.  I added that function and a couple other similar functions.  If you are still getting an error, try putting a break-point in the code and run it using the debugger.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: A couple more items... The range name that I put in the code will not work because it has a space in it.   Remove the space or change it to an underscore.  Also, When you define the range name, the scope must be the sheet name and not the workbook.  You need to define the same range name for both the source and target sheets (or else modify the code I gave you).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This has now worked. Sorry if I was a bit vague with my questions, I havent posted on here much. Thanks again :)