# C# - Add Ins Excel : how count rows?

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-addins

It's my first add ins excel in C#...

I would like know how do for count the rows who is completed in an excel file ?
I must complete a particular column with a specific value.
But for complete the column with this specific value, i must identify the rows who are completed in the sheet.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks !

Comment: [How to determine the last Row used in VBA including blank spaces in between](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686801/how-to-determine-the-last-row-used-in-vba-including-blank-spaces-in-between)

Comment: Thanks Stuartd !
But it's VBA... and i use C#, it's not the same functions...

Comment: Whether you use C# or VBA, you're calling the same functions in Excel, e.g. `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`