# Excel: Automating the Selection of an Unknown Number of Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to automate the formatting of an excel file by a macro and am seeking a solution.

I have two columns titled *Last Name* and *First Name* which I would like to concatenate into a separate column titled *Last Name, First Name.*

This is simple enough when done by hand: create one cell which does this, then drag that cell to include all cells within the range.  The problem appears when trying to automate this.  Because I can’t know the number of names that need to be concatenated ahead of time, I can’t automate the selection of cells by dragging.

Can you help me automate this?

I’ve tried a process of copying the initial concatenated cell, highlighting the column, and then pasting.  I’ve also tried to use a formula which returned the concatenation only if there is text in the “Last Name” and “First Name” columns.  However, in both cases, I end up with some 100,000 rows, putting a serious cramp on my ability to manipulate the worksheet.

The best solution I can think of is to create concatenations within a fixed range of cells.  Although this would create useless cells, at least there wouldn’t be 99,900 of them.

Comment: Normally you would use `Find` or the `xlUp` like finding techniques to define your range (`Find` is more versatile). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872512/last-not-empty-cell-in-row-excel-vba/8583926#8583926

Answer (score 1):

The [UsedRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa218185%28v=office.10%29.aspx) property can be used to figure out how many rows/columns need selecting on a sheet with an unknown about of data. [Here's an example](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/4413-select-used-range.html#post19503).

Answer (score 1):

You can make Excel automatically add formula to the field if required. Just fill three sells: First name - Last name - Formula. Then select the range and format it as a table (`Home -> Style -> Format as Table`) and Excel with automatically add formula for the third field if you put something in first of last name.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use in your `C1` formula `=A1&" "&B1` and them double click the black square and expand the function? And then Apply Filter?

Answer (score 0):

Here an example how to get your rows!

```
Sub ExampleNames()
Dim MaxRow As Long
Dim i As Long

MaxRow = Worksheet(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count  'For Excel 2010 and later

' OR

'MaxRow = Worksheets(1).Cells(1.1).UsedRange.Rows.Count  'For prior Excel Verisons

For i = 1 To MaxRow
    ' your code to string them together
Next i

End Sub
```