# Excel Mac VBA Loop Through Cells and reset some values

Tags: macos, excel, vba

I currently have a worksheet that I have multiple people filling out every day.  There are 4 columns that the users fill out: C, E, H, & J (all numerical values, one row per day of the month.)

The users fill in C, E, & H every day no matter what, but a lot of days there is no value to put in column J.  I need the value in J to be set to 0 if the user doesn't enter anything.  Of course it would be easier to just have the users enter 0, but I'm working with a complicated group of people here.

Anyway, I want to use a macro that runs automatically when the user clicks the save button (before it actually saves, of course), and have it do the following: (I am more familiar with php, so I'm just typing this out how I'm familiar - I'm sure my syntax is incorrect)

```
Foreach Row
  If "column A" != "" {
   If "column J" != "" {
    //Everything is good, continue on...
   } else {
    CurrentRow.ColumnJ.value == 0
   }//Value has been set - continue loop
  }
  //column A is blank, this day hasn't come yet - quit looping here
End Foreach
```

If anyone could help me out with this I'd appreciate it.  With some research, this is what I've come up with so far, and now I'm stuck…

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
 Dim curCell As Range
 'Labor Flow Sheet'.Select

 For Each curCell in Range( ???? )
  If curCell.Value = "" Then
   ???????
  End If
 Next curCell
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know if they haven't entered anything? Is there something in column A or B that indicates the date or the current row? BTW, we're all working with complicated groups of people. :-)

Comment: LOL Glad I'm not alone.  COL B is MTD Sales dollars, COL A calculates the Daily Sales dollars by subtracting yesterday's sales dollars from Today's MTD.  I have an IF statement in column A that assigns a value of "" (nothing) if the user hasn't entered anything in COL B, otherwise it does the Daily Sales calculation.  I could go off of either one of these columns, really.  I just need to check if the cell value is NULL or EMPTY or whatever the proper word for "" is in Excel world.

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872512/last-not-empty-cell-in-row-excel-vba/8583926#8583926) about finding the right range, and as for the question marks inside the If statement, you would want to put

```
curCell.Value = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For the question marks in your statement

```
For Each curCell in Range( ???? )
```

Solution 1:
To find the full range you're working with, you'll need to use a column that is filled out each day. You mentioned columns C, E, and H were filled out every day. Using one of those columns (let's pick C for the example here), you could find the range by using the .end method. This goes out either up down left or right from a range until it doesn't find any data. So,

```
Range("J1", Range("C1").End(xlDown)).Select
```

will select all cells from J1 (or whatever column is the last in your sheet) to the bottom-most cell containing data in column C, *automatically*.

Solution 2:
Manually put in the range. For example, to choose A1 to J300:

```
Range("A1", "J300").Select
```

Comment: LOVE IT!  Thanks so much for helping me select the proper range automatically!  Any input on how to check for values in the C column and put in a 0 on the J column if necessary?

Comment: If you liked, please vote up! I think the code you first posted will work fine now with some minor tweaks - I'll try to post later.

Comment: I tried to vote up, but apparently I'm too New, LOL.  I will do it as soon as I get enough points.  My problem with the looping & the If statements is the syntax, I have the concept down.  If you get some time, I appreciate it!

Comment: Hey any advice on checking & replacing those values? Thank you!!

Comment: Sure, I'd suggest looking into the range.replace method for replacing values. You might consider posting another question for details. BTW, you might also check out superuser.com - it's a sister site to this one, and more geared towards beginning questions with excel (you can still use excel and os-x tags).

Comment: Sweet, I'll check it out.  I appreciate the input @Aaron