# define a range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

I have a range of data that will be between columns B and D inclusive.

I can get the top left most range as this will be constant, the only thing that varies is the bottom right cell.

I tried obtaining the bottom right cell via using xltoright and then xltobottom. However I am having difficulties obtaining the cell address of this bottom right cell.

Has anyone come across this problem and if so how did you over come the issue?

Comment: Simple :) Use `.Find` :) See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: you can find a lot of answet to that question here. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) post is one example.

Comment: @sid lol, i reference the OP to the same link :P

Comment: So many questions.  [an earlier one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4872512/641067)

Comment: `CurrentRegion` could work e.g. `Set rng = Range('B1').CurrentRegion`

Comment: Are you able to get to the bottom right cell? You can use cell.address to get that address.  So, if your top left cell is A1, you can try: 

`Dim lastCell
lastCell = Cells(1,1).End(xltoRight).End(xlDown).Address`

Answer (score 0):

change xltoright and then xltobottom, to : xltoleft and then xlUp.
Check the answers you get from it in the immédiate window of VB editor (Ctrl+G)

if still doesn't work maybe use:

```
Range(Range_Adddress).cells.(Range(RangeAddress).cells.count).address
```

to get to the last cell's address of your range (I named it Range_Address, which has to be a string in the example).

Does this help you?