# How to insert row at the end of a range in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a row at the bottom of the range, but nothing happens when I run the below code. If I remove the "1" in

```
Cells(nextRow, 1).EntireRow.Insert
```

It will insert a row at the top of the range.

```
Sub newRow()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Sheet1.Activate

'goes to the row at the bottom of the range
nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1

'inserts new row
Cells(nextRow, 1).EntireRow.Insert

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are already at the bottom where the blank rows are, why are you inserting a new row? What are you expecting to move down?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741836/how-to-select-the-lastrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting a row at the bottom of the range is not visible - and it is an empty row, which is not different than the unused empty rows. Anyway, inserting a row before the last one of the range is quite visible:

```
Sub NewRow()

    Dim nextRow As Long

    With Sheet1
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(nextRow, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Usin With `Sheet1` and `.Cells()` instead of Select and Activate is a good practice -[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)