# Finding row count in vba - method explanation

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying t0 find the row count of a particular column using vba,

I have found that it can be done by using two methods, all three of which involve range ( I pretty much found this by a simple google search and then editing what I found to suit my needs)

However I feel that it would suit me better if I understood what each of them did and how they were different from each other

The two codes I used are as follows :

```
i = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))

lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Could anyone please explain me how these two work and what is the difference between the two? Also, if you know any other way that's efficient, it would be helpful if you do share it here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: Using `CountA` will give you the total number of occupied cells and not the last row. To find the last row, use the second one or as shown in the link above.

Answer (score 3):

```
i = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
```

This returns the count of all the cells in column A that contain a value. They do not have to  be in consecutive cells.

```
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

This goes to the very last cell at the bottom of column A then does the equivalent of pressing the End key and then the up arrow key. This will return the row index of last cell in the column that contains a value.

Comment: `This will select the last cell in the column that contains a value.` + 1 :) However, It will `NOT SELECT` the last cell as you mentioned above :)

Comment: Rather than "select", I'd use "return" though. Both methods above gets and returns a value, rather than move and actively change a selection. ;)

Comment: Should’t the first one be `i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))`?

Comment: When the methods are called without object qualifier, they are run on `Workbook.ActiveSheet`. The dots before the method names are important.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Find` is superior

- Unlike `xlUp` caters for hidden cells (but not filtered out cells)
- Avoids false reporting for blank or the far less likely full column. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872512/last-not-empty-cell-in-row-excel-vba/8583926#8583926)

*Find method*

```
Sub GetLastA()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Columns("A:A").Find("*", [a1], xlFormulas)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "last row is " & rng1.Row
Else
  MsgBox "no used cells found", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub row_cownt()
Dim R As Double
Dim C As Double

R = Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

C = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column


MsgBox "Row =" & R
MsgBox "Column =" & C
End Sub
```