# Find last element in column

Tags: excel, vba

I found a method online of finding the last row in a chart using the following code

```
Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlPrevious).Row
```

How can I adapt this to find the last cell in a particualr column, say G for example, I've tried changing the range, but it hasn't produced expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should help find the last row in column G of the active sheet:

```
'Find the last used row in a Column: column G in this example
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    MsgBox LastRow
End Sub
```

It was taken from http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm which is a very useful article for finding last columns and rows in your sheet.

The following SO Q&As are also a very useful resource for what you're looking for:

- [How can I find last row that contains data in the Excel sheet with a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)
- [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)
- [Last not empty cell in row; Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872512/last-not-empty-cell-in-row-excel-vba/8583926#8583926)

Comment: Superb, I'd looked at the first site you posted, but must have missed something when I first attempted it, because it works now.

Comment: @SuperKOM: I'm glad I was able to help. Good luck!