# Creating a table for the sheet, depending on the data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet "Missing". This sheet is generally a part of data from my another sheet "data".

I would like to have the content of my missing sheet always wrapped in a table.

I tried the below code,

```
   Sub LoopingThroughTable()
         Sheets("Missing").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$1:$D$16"), , xlYes).Name = _
             "Table19"       
         Sheets("Missing").ListObjects("Table19").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight12"
    End Sub
```

but with this code, I need to always mention the range. As I told earlier, Since it is an data from another sheet, the row length can vary.

so eevrytime I extract the data from my sheet Data to result, I always wanted to draw a table only for the available content.

Can anyone help, how I can do this  ?

Comment: set the range dynamically with the row count of your other sheet then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last not empty cell in row; Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872512/last-not-empty-cell-in-row-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the data on the "missing" sheet starts at B1 you can assign a variable for the last row and use that in the range.
So your code will be something like:

```
Sub LoopingThroughTable()
    lastrow = Worksheets("Missing").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Missing").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$1:$D$" & lastrow), , xlYes).Name = _
         "Table19"       
    Sheets("Missing").ListObjects("Table19").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight12"
End Sub
```

Im also assuming the current code works.

Comment: The code works. But the problem now is, the table is getting overlapped.

Comment: and each time I am running my code, It says, table can not be overlapped with another table

Comment: This happens even when you manually type in the range? Also I made a correction on the `lastrow` variable.