# Duplicate as Value only last row into adjacent column Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a VBA application with some forms. When the data is inserted into the Table, Column A calculates a value with a formula. After that I need to copy the resulting value (like paste special, values only) into the adjacent Row
[image: Copy Last Row from Column A to Last Row Column B]

I just need to know how to select the last row everytime. I have tried with `ActiveCell`, `Find`, `Range` etc. but none are working

```
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` this would return the last row for column A in the `ActiveSheet`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 1):

From a programming point of view, it's much better to define variables rather than using `Selection, .select, or ActiveCell,` etc... This code will place the cell you are looking for into the variable `r`, assuming the first header row (A1) is not empty. If you don't want to make any assumptions about the first or last row, see the last answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453658/find-the-last-cell-address-using-vba-excel). In the code below, this would mean replacing `Set r = r.End(xlDown)` with `Set r = sh.Range("A:A").Find("*", Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)`

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim sh As Worksheet, r As Range
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set r = sh.Range("A1")
Set r = r.End(xlDown)
r.Select 'remove after code has been tested and you know it works
End Sub
```

If you have more questions, just ask. There's a lot of help available to help you program in the proper way here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks Tony, i figured it out with this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,
I fixed it with help of both

```
    LastValue = Range("Table1[Opportunity no.]").End(xlDown).Value
Set ws = Worksheets("Datos")
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    With ws
    .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = LastValue
    End With
```