# "For loop not initialized"

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to run the the script but once it reached blank cell the macro just stopped.

I also tried input some text on each blank cell but "For loop not initialized" appear.

Please see the code I used down below:

```
Sub test()

    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim descriptions() As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Range("O3").End(xlDown).Row

        For i = lastrow To 3 Step -1
            If InStr(1, .Range("O" & i).Value, ",") \<\> 0 Then
                descriptions = Split(.Range("O" & i).Value, ",")
            End If

            For Each Item In descriptions
                .Range("O" & i).Value = Item
                .Rows(i).Copy
                .Rows(i).Insert
            Next Item

            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Please see attached screenshot here.]

Thank you in advanced.

I expected for the script to run through and insert row if cell have commas.

Comment: `\<\>` is no valid syntax and should be `<>`.

Comment: When you single step through the code, on the line: `lastrow = .Range("O3").End(xlDown).Row`, what value do you expect `lastrow` to get and what does it actually get? What you need to do is said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11454454/2292722

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Insert Split Cell Values

- Instead of `.Rows(r).Insert`, you should consider using `.Cells(r, "O").Insert` for the rest of the columns not to be affected.
- On the other hand, if you have data in the other columns that need to be copied, in the middle of the inner loop, slip in the line `.Rows(r).Copy`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SplitDescriptions()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        
        Dim Descriptions() As String, dUpper As Long, d As Long
        Dim r As Long, rString As String 
        
        For r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
            rString = CStr(.Cells(r, "O").Value)
            If InStr(rString, ",") > 0 Then
                Descriptions = Split(rString, ",")
                dUpper = UBound(Descriptions)
                For d = 0 To dUpper
                    .Cells(r, "O").Value = Descriptions(d)
                    If d < dUpper Then .Rows(r).Insert
                Next d
            End If
         Next r
    
    End With

End Sub
```

- To get the order *left-to-right* as *top-to-bottom*, replace the inner loop with the following.

```vb
                For d = dUpper To 0 Step -1
                    .Cells(r, "O").Value = Descriptions(d)
                    If d > 0 Then .Rows(r).Insert
                Next d
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, everything working perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible to do it for 2 ranges?