# Powerpoint VBA: How to get last used column in a row from an Excel sheet

Tags: vba, powerpoint, excel-2003

**Q:** How do I get the last used column in a specific row from an Excel sheet.
While this is [a simple task using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301665/excel-vba-row-number-of-last-cell-with-data) its more difficult using Powerpoint VBA.

Here is an example of my Excel sheet

[image]

**Steps to reproduce**

- create & save a new Excel sheet like my example above
- open a new PowerPoint presentation & hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> for the VBA editor
- insert the code below and customize the path to your test Excel file in line 3
- execute the code line per line using <kbd>F8</kbd>

```vb
Sub findlastcolumn()

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\data.xls")

    objExcel.Visible = True

    'works in Powerpoint VBA but delivers the wrong column
    lastcol = objWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'produces an error in Powerpoint VBA
    'but works in Excel VBA, correct column in Excel VBA
    lastcol = objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 254).End(Direction:=xlToLeft).Column

    'produces an error in Powerpoint VBA
    'but works in Excel VBA, and wrong column in Excel VBA too
    lastcol = objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column

    'wrong column. Powerpoint VBA' find method differs from Excel' find method
    'searchdirection isn't available in Powerpoint VBA
    lastcol = objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Find(what:="*", _ 
        after:=objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    objExcel.Quit
    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Desired result:** I want to get lastcol = 3

The comments in my code show you what I have tried so far and what error they produce.
I'm thankful for any advice.

<sup>There is no PowerPoint 2003 tag? O.o</sup>

Comment: +1 for "beautifully asked question". Would recommend you edit the example - wrap your code a bit for readability...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Excel specific code you posted should actually work and give you the same result as if you execute it in Excel.

The reason you do get error message is most likely that you did not in include the Excel reference in your Powerpoint VBA! You do use Late Binding, so it's generally not necessary to reference this library. However, the VBA compiler does not know the internal values of the Excel constants/enums `xlToLeft`, `xlLastCell` and `xlPrevious` and therefore produces the error!

Two options to solve your issue:

1. Include the Microsoft Excel library in your references
2. Instead of using the Excel specific conmstants/enums, just use their underlying numerical values. To do so, go to the Excel Visual Basic editor. In the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>), type `? xlToLeft` - and you'll get the result (in this example `-4159`). Then replace the name in your Powerpoint VBA with the number and it should work. (For better code readability, I usually leave the name of the constant in a comment in the same line, e.g.

   ```
   lastcol = objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(11).Column 'xlLastCell = 11
   ```

Comment: +1 for teaching me how to get underlying numerical values of constants

Answer (score 1):

@nixada, You **can** do it from **POWERPOINT** vba:

You need to get to the workbook object: (assuming you have the excel data in slide #1, on chart #1:

```
Set cht = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart
Set DataWorkBook = cht.ChartData.Workbook
```

Then you should get your last blank column using the blank type:

```
LastCol = DataWorkBook.Sheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(4).Column -1 'xlCellTypeBlanks = 4
```

That should give you the desired answer "**3**"

*Note*: for the list of types you can refer to [XlCellType enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcelltype)

**EDIT:** Using xlCellTypeLastCell  ( = 11: The last cell in the used range) ***will not necessary give you the desired answer*** as if a cell was used but its content now deleted, it will be considered as used cell in the range.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do. *** proviso: untested code. If this doesn't work, tell me in the comments ***

```
Dim r as Range
Dim col = 0
set r = objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
while(** test that r has something in it **)
  col = col + 1
  set r = r.offset(0, 1)
end
```

I don't have the setup handy to figure out what the test should be - but that ought to be easy. The point is that this doesn't use constants the Powerpoint VBA doesn't know (like xlDown).

Comment: This works. But: My little example above was only for a showcase. The real Excel data can be very large. Looping through every cell is not what I was looking for. The performance loss will be too huge :( --- btw. your initial code only works if there are no blank cells. But if you go backwards, it will work.

Comment: Glad it helped. Unless you have to do this multiple times, you'd be surprised how fast your code will run through these cells. I doubt you can tell the code is even running. If it's a problem, you could put `=counta("A1:whatever your last cell minus one is")` in the last cell of the spreadsheet, see what the number is. That is the "number of cells with something in it". Take the .Value of that cell, then erase it. If this code works, you might "accept" the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I just want to post the corrected code if anyone stumbles over a similar issue. (Thanks to [Peter Albert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14552558/935614))

```
Sub findlastcolumn()

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\input data.xls")        
    objExcel.Visible = True
    icolumn = 1 'which column should be checked (in sheet 1) 

    'works
    Set r = objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(icolumn, objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns.Count)
    Do: Set r = r.offset(0, -1)
    Loop While r.Value = ""
    lastcol1 = r.Column

    'works
    lastcol2 = objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(icolumn, _ 
       objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(Direction:=-4159).Column

    'works
    lastcol3 = objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(icolumn).Find(what:="*", _
        after:=objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=2).Column

    'works - but not if your columns have different last cells
    lastcol4 = objWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'works - but not if your columns have different last cells
    lastcol5 = objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(11).Column

End Sub
```

Comment: That's just great!! but... as the question asks - how do you do it from powerpoint vba???