# usedrange giving wrong column number

Tags: vba, excel

```
 Sub testing()


    'start searching for address
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    IncNum = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    ExcNum = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    InrNum = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Exrnum = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Set sheet1Table = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    Set sheet2Table = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange
    'skip header
    For InrCounter = 2 To InrNum
        For ExrCounter = 2 To Exrnum
            If sheet1Table.Cells(InrCounter, 1) = sheet2Table.Cells(ExrCounter, 1) And sheet1Table.Cells(InrCounter, 2) = sheet2Table.Cells(ExrCounter, 2) And sheet1Table.Cells(InrCounter, 3) = sheet2Table.Cells(ExrCounter, 3) Then
                If IncNum = ExcNum Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Dim LastCofRowCounter, lastCofthisR As Integer
                    lastCofthisR = sheet1Table.Cells(ExrCounter, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    For LastCofRowCounter = lastCofthisR + 1 To IncNum
                        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ExrCounter, LastCofRowCounter) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(InrCounter, LastCofRowCounter)
                    Next LastCofRowCounter
                End If
            ElseIf ExrCounter = Exrnum Then

        'fid the last row of mastersheet
        lrowEx = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        For counterCofLastR = 1 To IncNum
           Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lrowEx + 1, counterCofLastR) = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells(InrCounter, counterCofLastR)
        Next counterCofLastR
        End If
      Next ExrCounter

Next InrCounter
End Sub


    the table looks like  
        h1 h2 h3 h4
        x  x  x  x
```

the line ExcNum = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count is giving me 9 instead of 4 and I have no idea why in this case...i tried on another worksheet with the same table and it worked fine.

I tried to call

```
  Sub ResetUsedRng()
    Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  End Sub
```

before executing all the code but this did not work. I also read the related posts you guys linked which includes this

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave _
     (ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
     For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      x = Sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
      Next Sh
    End Sub
```

I called     Call Workbook_BeforeSave(True, False), which did not work either. Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the used range [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423022/excel-getting-the-actual-usedrange/7423252#7423252)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel is notoriously bad about updating the `.UsedRange` property. If your sheet at some point had data or formatting applied in column `I`, then it's likely that the `.UsedRange` property was never updated.

Since `.UsedRange` is so handy to use in VBA, I usually workaround this by crafting a sub that checks for the last occupied column and row in the sheet and *Deletes* any extra rows and columns included in `Sheet.UsedRange`. This will force an update of the property.

Comment: thanks for the insight can you give me a few lines of sample to do this? I am completely new to excel vba.@Excellll

Comment: See the link in Reafidy's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience the only reliable one is to use

```
Lastcol =  Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
Lastrow =  Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

to determine the last cell of a used range. All other methos involving `UsedRange` or `SpecialCells(xlLastCell)` or `End(xlUp)` [may give you wrong results.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14390619/935614)

Answer (score -1):

This two line do the  magic. It uses specialcells to find out last column and last row.

```
  usedCol = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
  usedRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

For more info visit  Microsoft's site

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx