# macro in vba that find some string in some cells

Tags: excel, vba

I try to do a macro that can find it some strings in some cells, but I have a error.

My code is:

```
Sub MACRO()
    bAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim Totalrows As Integer
    Dim Totalcols As Integer
    Dim Valor As String
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Totalrows = Worksheets(i).UsedRange.rows.Count
        Totalcols = Worksheets(i).UsedRange.Columns.Count
        For r = 1 To Totalrows
            For c = 1 To Totalcols
                If InStr(Worksheets(i).Cells(r, c), "cadena buscada") > 0 Then
                    MsgBox "Se encontró una coincidencia"
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bAlerts
End Sub
```

I have an error in this line:

```
If InStr(Worksheets(i).Cells(r, c), "cadena buscada") > 0 Then
```

Anyone knows where is the error ?

Thanks!

Comment: what's the error, specifically?   You can make sure i, r, and c have valid values.  That'd be a good start.  Running your code on my test workbook doesn't throw and errors.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. It might be that the counts are incorrect. FYI, UsedRange is not the best way to find "used range".

Answer (score 0):

> my string I want to find, is a formula like this =C:\Gestion...

The most likely issue is that your cell on the sheet contains error, like `#N/A` or `#DIV/0!` and so on.

Loop through each cell is unefficient. Use `.Find` method instead:

```
Sub MACRO()
    Dim bAlerts
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim fAddr As String

    bAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.UsedRange
            Set rng = .Find(What:="cadena buscada", _
                                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                        MatchCase:=False)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                fAddr = rng.Address
                Do
                    MsgBox "Match found in sheet: " & ws.Name & ", cell: " & rng.Address
                    Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
                    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Loop While fAddr <> rng.Address
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bAlerts
End Sub
```

I also changed `For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count` to `For Each ws In Worksheets` because it's slightly faster.

Comment: I try this, but I can't find this string "cadena buscada" in my excel. My program don't find it this string

Comment: check whether you really have this substring in your sheet. Try to find it manually in sheet using CTRL+F

Comment: Simoco, Find is very Inefficient not sure, in this case if it is faster, but, in my tests looping, most of the time is faster...but its a good idea to time it for this case    :)

Comment: @CRondao, if you have 10 cells in used range, loop may be faster. But in real sheet whith data find is more efficient way

Comment: Okey, well, my string I want to find, is a formula like this =C:\Gestion... How I can find this

Comment: @simoco, you should backup your saying with facts, speed will depend on many things, range size, number of matches... etc. Its a range A1:Z250 real enough for you? Sure much more than 10 cells. See my answer update and test it, you will be suprised...

Answer (score 0):

Update your column and row count to a more stable extraction set [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301665/row-number-of-last-cell-with-data) so that it associates with the entire worksheet used range, rather than standardized used range which breaks on blank cells.

```
Sub MACRO()
    bAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim Totalrows As Integer
    Dim Totalcols As Integer
    Dim Valor As String
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Totalrows = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        Totalcols = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        For r = 1 To Totalrows
            For c = 1 To Totalcols
                If InStr(Worksheets(i).Cells(r, c), "cadena buscada") > 0 Then
                    MsgBox "Se encontró una coincidencia"
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bAlerts
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you have an error in any of the used cells, if so add this to your code:

```
if not IsError(worksheets(i).cells(r,c)) then
  if InStr....
```

To look closer to efficiency try this code

```
Sub MACRO1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim fAddr As String, p As Long
Set ws = Sheet1
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set rng = .Find(What:=18, _
                                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                    MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            fAddr = rng.Address
            Do
                p = p + 1
                Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
                If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While fAddr <> rng.Address
        End If
    End With
'MsgBox p
End Sub

Sub macro2()
Dim ws, c, p As Long
Set ws = Sheet1.UsedRange
For Each c In ws
 If c = 18 Then
  p = p + 1
  End If
Next
'MsgBox p
End Sub
Sub macro3()
Dim ws, c, p As Long, v
Dim nr As Long, nc As Long, r As Long
Set ws = Sheet1.UsedRange
nr = ws.Rows.Count
nc = ws.Columns.Count
v = ws
For r = 1 To nr
 For c = 1 To nc
  If v(r, c) = 18 Then
   p = p + 1
  End If
 Next
Next
'MsgBox p
End Sub

Sub TimeIt()
Dim t1 As Single, t2 As Single
Dim p As Integer, t3 As Single
t1 = Timer
For p = 1 To 300
 MACRO1
Next
t1 = Timer - t1
t2 = Timer
For p = 1 To 300
 macro2
Next
t2 = Timer - t2
t3 = Timer
For p = 1 To 300
 macro3
Next
t3 = Timer - t3
MsgBox t1 & Chr(13) & t2 & Chr(13) & t3
End Sub
```

With a used range about A1:Z250 filled with integer random numbers 1-20 and looking for all the matches of the value 18, in my computer the times were:

```
macro1 (using Find) 5.76 secs
macro2 (looping with For each) 3.94 secs
macro3 (looping using an array) 0.6 secs
```

If there is only one match macro1 and macro3 took both abou 0.6 secs

So if we have several possible matches FIND is the most inefficient (almost, in this case, 9 times slower.

Comment: 1) I said that `.Find` is faster than looping through _cells_ (but not array) 2) if you look at OP's comment below my answer, `my string I want to find, is a formula like this =C:\Gestion...` - so storing range in array and then loop doesn't work, because search should be made _in formulas_ but not in their result values. That's why `.Find` is best suited here

Comment: That's no longer what we're talking about, i just said that find is not always faster and it is not, and as you can see, even without arrays, with several matches, looping in cells was faster. It's a shame when someone have problems saying...."Ok I was not completly right" even faced with facts.....but ok, discussion is over...