# Excel VBA - Assign row to variable and manipulate it?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been searching how to assign a row to a variable and manipulate cells through the variable but I can't seem to find how to do this.

```
x = Sheet5.Range("A1").EntireRow
    MsgBox x(1, 1)
```

The above code will get me the row into 'x', but is there any way that I can change a cells value using the variable 'x'? x(1,1) = "foo" will not work, and since it's not an object I can't access .Value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample code:

```
Sub Ranging()
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("A1").EntireRow
    With rng
        Debug.Print .Cells(1).Value
        Debug.Print .Cells(5).Address
        .Cells(43).Value = "SurfN'Turf"
    End With
End Sub
```

`Debug.Print` prints to the VBE's Immediate Window (access with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks. New to Excel VBA so I had no idea about the Set keyword. Within the With/EndWith is there a way to grab the next (or last) blank row?

Comment: That's a frequent topic on SO. I generally use the first option in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15052318/293078, but sometimes the `Previous` version is necessary. Happy coding!