# Excel Row Counting Not Working

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a VBA Macro that is working with a very large dataset.
In my dataset I have ~44000 rows. I want to count this within the macro and have tried to use the top methods shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301665/how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-in-excel-with-data).

I take variable sncountmax and make it equal to one of the methods in the link above.

```
sncountmax = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

Even though the sheet contains 44000 rows sncountmax will remain set to whatever it was previously set to.

EDIT: I have since checked and no other macro functions are executing on this sheet. I tried to remove duplicates using the macro and this did not work, but removing the duplicates in Excel did.

Comment: Broken link, whatever its supposed to point to should probably be in the question.

Comment: Link fixed. Sorry for not including it here explicitly but the link points to the code that I have used here

Comment: @LewisHeslop I cannot reproduce your problem with the limited information you have provided.  So the problem likely lies in other lines of code that you do not share with us; your data; the defaults for the `.Find` method that you have not explicitly set, or possibly something in your environment.

Comment: @LewisHeslop As an example, since you did not specify it, you may get a different return value depending on the saved value of the `Lookin` constant and the nature of your data.  Also, the last row will be that on whatever sheet is active at the time you run this macro.

Comment: The macro is acting on an excel workbook with multiple sheets, the macro grabs data from hundreds of xml files and orders them under headings, one of the headings is a serial number heading. Once all xml files have been grabbed I am trying to count the number of rows.

Comment: @LewisHeslop If the comment above is directed to me, it does not address any of the issues I have raised.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It was more general. What information would you like me to provide?

Comment: That should be clear from my comments. Also please read help for how to provide an example.

Comment: Is the sheet you're trying to find the last row on the active sheet?  Your code states 'Cells.Find(....)' - without telling it what sheet to work on it finds the last row on the currently active sheet.

Comment: Once you have the code running - it will fail if there is no data on the sheet as it tries to find row 0.  I find it easier to pass the whole thing out to a function.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing to the following:

```
sncountmax = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

This will give the last row in Column A, so in your situation `scountmax = 44000`

Comment: They both work.  I like the `"A"` method just because I don't always want to count the columns in a scenario where I need to count the rows in Column AQ ;)

Comment: The main reason of using `Cells` is that it calculates ~33% faster than `Range` if used with just numerical values. But using it with strings will make it slower than `Range`. While it won't matter in this case, but if you want to use the "A" Then you will be faster by using `sncountmax = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` :P

Comment: I am currently restarting my macro, if my problems persist, I will try this. I have a feeling this will be unrelated, because as I said in my edit, other lines of the macro were not being executed correctly.

Comment: @DirkReichel  if you have justification or tests that will prove information provided in your comments please provide it, otherwise it's just words

Comment: What @Dirk Reichel is saying makes perfect sense, and I agree that searching by integers is generally faster than searching by characters.  That being said, in this case it won't make a noticeable difference.  But I do like the `sncountmax = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` version he provided

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't advise using `find`. Its not reliable as for sometimes it can return nothing depending on Data, and it's slower.

If your sole purpose is counting the lines in the first column :

```
with thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1")
    sncountmax = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
end with
```

Reference the sheets and workbooks like the above example.

You might want to use `Option Explicit` on the top of your module.

Also, i can only guess, but you should remove your `Òn Error Resume Next`.
Errors are meaning your code is wrong somewhere.