# Find last constant in a column and then highlight data based on it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to use VBA to do the following in Excel versions 2003, 2007, 2010 (hopefully it's the same for all of them):
Search for the last cell in column A with a constant value in it.
Select all data from A2:I2 to the row with the last constant data value in it from the search above.

For example, if the last row with constant data in column A is A13, then I would want to select A2:I2 through A13:I13.

Comment: (i) what do mean by constant data? (ii) what have you tried?

Comment: A constant in Excel is data in a cell that is not calculated.  For example, I use vlookups in a couple of columns.  If I use the SpecialCells.xlLastCell, it will return the incorrect row, because it sees the vlookup formulas as "data".  You can see this if you use Find & Select, Go To...Special and select Constants.  Excel will only select "real" data, not data that is calculated in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit***

**Now 'lastRow' will find the last used cell in column A even if there are blanks up above.  This assumes the equations are in other columns as your comment suggested.**

```
Sub SelectRange()
  lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  Range("A2:I" & lastRow).Select
End Sub
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro) for how to find last cell in different versions of excel.

---

Say you did have to evaluate the cells in column A for formulas versus constants you can use the HasFormula method like this:

```
Sub SelectRange()
  lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  Do While Range("A" & lastRow).HasFormula <> False
    lastRow = Cells(lastRow - 1, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Loop

  Range("A2:I" & lastRow).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, because I have calculated fields in columns E and F (vlookups), and Excel sees that as "data".  Is there a way for me to just look in column A for the last data value in a cell, then select those rows from column A - I?  The pseudocode would be: find last cell in column A that has any data in it; now select A2 through last cell in column A with data in it.  Now select all columns through column I.  For example: if the last data cell in A is at A13, my code would select A2:I2 through A13:I13.  Thanks so much for your assistance!

Comment: Is there any blank cells between the A1 and the last cell in column A?  I can make a faster routine if there are no blanks.

Comment: Who's the man?  Portland Runner is the MAN!  Thanks for the solution!