# VBA Loop to Count

Tags: vba, loops

I've got experience in coding through Matlab, but have never done VBA. I have an Excel file I download daily and the number of rows is not consistent.  The column titles I want to work with are "Uptime","Team", and "Reason1". The data does not start until row 15 and the row it ends on varies daily.

I need to count the number of times two consecutive rows of data have an uptime value of 0.0, different values for team, and the same values for Reason1.

Here is how I began writing my code from what I have looked up online.

```
Dim Uptime As Integer, Team as Integer, Reason1 As Integer
Uptime=Range(I15:I). value   **values start in the 15th row**
Team=Range(H15:I)
Reason1=Range(N15:N)
i=15
n=0
Do While (B15:B) like "*DIMP*"        **Every row with data has DIMP in column B**
If Uptime like "0.0" and Team(i,H) <> Team((i-1),H) and Reason1(i,N) like Reason1((i-1),N)
Count=n+1
```

**So I want this loop to go through each row where DIMP is in column B and then terminate, what code do I need to add to terminate**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find last row that contains data in the Excel sheet with a macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to find the last row in a column that has data in it. Obivously just switch out A for the column you want and Sheet1 for the sheet name.

```
 lastRow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Sheets("sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
```

You can then use a simple for loop to iterate through the rows

```
for i = 1 to lastRow
    'do something in here
next i
```