# Excel Macro to scan column for a blank cell, then insert current time

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

After a few hours of searching I can not find any examples of how to perform this.

I am trying to create 2 buttons on my excel sheet for time tracking purposes (for easily logging my day to day activities).  A clock-in button, and a clock-out button. The buttons are set up and work, with the proper script. Currently they just write the current time to the selected cell using the following:

```
ActiveCell.Value = Time
```

This works fine, but I would like something a little more automated.
What I would like each button to do is scan the column (clock-in for example is column C) from row 2 to  the first blank cell, then insert the current time into that cell (So C2 would have *Time*). Next time the button is pressed, it will input *Time* into C3. Next press would input *Time* to C4, etc etc etc. That is the basic idea of what I am trying to do.

I am trying to do this in Excel 2007, if that matters
**Bonus:**
How to do both clock-in/clock-out with one button. Not needed, but would be interesting to see.

Thanks,

Rich

Comment: If *time in* is in C where is *time out*?

Comment: Yo do not provide any code or effort to write your own code. Ok you have an idea how it should work, but that is not enough. This is not how SO works. To solve your problem check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro. Maybe the workbooks.open event is interesting for you too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff194819%28v=office.15%29.aspx if the code is not working, come back post the code and we will help you with it.

Comment: This is super easy. So in your code find the last row in column Can. Google how to there 100s examples. Then cell.value = myvalue

Comment: whats the purpose of clock in/out? Is it to track when file is open and when file is closed, right? And same question as L42 : where does clock out goes, col D or what?

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) will get you started.

Comment: *hours of searching...?* wow....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub clock_in()
    Cells(2, 3).Select ' starts at cell C2
    Do Until ActiveCell = ""
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    ActiveCell = Time
End Sub
```

How it works: This routine starts at cell `C2` and works its way down the column looking for the first blank cell using a `Do Loop` statement. Once it finds a blank cell the do loop ends and the time is placed in the blank (active) cell.

Comment: An explanation of what you're doing here would be helpful.

Comment: This routine starts at cell C2 and works its way down the column looking for the first blank cell using a Do Loop statement. Once it finds a blank cell the do loop ends and the time is placed in the blank (active) cell.

Comment: This also does the job great, and simple. I had originally been trying to do something along the lines of your other answer. The selection.end was throwing me off because I never use VBA.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
Sub clock_in()
    Cells(2, 3).Select ' starts at cell C2
    If Cells(2, 3) = "" Then
        Cells(2, 3) = Time
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Cells(3, 3) = "" Then
        Cells(3, 3) = Time
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Time
End Sub
```

This routing checks to see if cell `C2` is empty. If it is it places the time in cell `C2`. If it isn't empty, it checks cell `C3` and places the time in that cell. But if `C3` is not empty, it uses an `end select` statement to find the next blank cell. The reason it checks for cell `C2` & `C3` is that if you do an `end select` statement and cell `C2` or `C3` are blank it will go to the bottom of column `C` in your spreadsheet.

Comment: This routing checks to see if cell C2 is empty ... if it is it places the time in cell C2. if it isn't empty, it checks cell C3 and places the time in that cell.. but if C3 is not empty, it uses an end select statement to find the next blank cell. The reason it checks for cell C2 & C3 is if you do an end select statement and cell C2 or C3 are blank ... it will go to the bottom of cloumn C in your spreadsheet.

Comment: This does exactly what I want it to do.