# VBA-Copy specific Column Data from multiple worksheets into one

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a very typical scenario where two columns from different worksheets(in same workbook) needs to be copied to single worksheet.

**Source workbook name:** Mycalc.xlsm

**Worksheets name:** Sheet1, sheet2, sheet3 (There are other sheets as well but action t o be performed only for the mentioned)

**Target Workbook Name:** Mycalc.xlsm

**Target worksheet name:** Merged

**Condition:**

1. Cannot do for each for all worksheets in the the workbook as the action to be performed only on the mentioned three sheets.
2. The columns headers are not necessarily in same order in all sheets but the header is same.

[image]    [image]      [image]

**Result Expected:**
The resultant is a consolidated data from all 3 sheets along with a column sheetname mentioning the sheet where data copied.

I am no expert in this and hence i am not pasting the code whatever i have achieved. Adding to it, I have approached by adding the sheet name in a named range as list (in a workbook i created a table having the list of sheet names and for each is performed on that range).

[image]

The experts of stackoverflow, please help me.

Regards,

Mani

Comment: Recommendation one: Use the [Worksheets(shname).Cells.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method, retrieve the header's column (and row since you didn't even make them uniform). Use the same method to retrieve their [last rows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25509398/3819867).

Comment: @katz .Please read with attention, i've clearly mentioned that i have not pasted my code to make the question simple and also i have also mentioned the approach. Nobody here requires service, its a forum which means discussion and helping.

Comment: @katz please find my code and works done. Hope you're happy now. Please be sure before down voting a question because it costs reputation (pts).

Comment: @ManivannanKG I haven't downvoted your question, I've just left a comment...

Answer (score 1):

I have used the concept of named range for the sheet names. After lot of hurdles and time consuming research. Here is a simple, compiles and working code.

> ```
> Public Sub ExportData()
>
> Dim TransCol(1 To 2) As String
> Dim ImportWS As Worksheet
> Dim SheetsName As Range
> Dim FindColumn, TargetColumn As Range
> Dim RowCount As Long
> Dim RowIndex, i, Column  As Long
> Dim LastUsedRow As Long
> Dim LastUsedRowCount As Variant
>
>
>     TransCol(1) = "ISIN"
>     TransCol(2) = "Current Day Adjustment"
>
>
>
> For Each SheetsName In sheet3.Range("tblSheetNames").Cells
>
>  If Len(SheetsName.Value) > 0 Then
>
>  Set ImportWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetsName.Value)
>  ImportWS.Activate
>
>  For Column = 1 To 2
>
>  Set FindColumn = ImportWS.Cells.Find(TransCol(Column), searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)
>      RowCount = FindColumn.Cells(200000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
>  Set TargetColumn = sheet3.Cells.Find(TransCol(Column), searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)
>
> For i = FindColumn.Row To RowCount
>
>     LastUsedRow = sheet3.Cells(200000, TargetColumn.Column).End(xlUp).Row
>     sheet3.Cells(LastUsedRow + 1, TargetColumn.Column).Value = ImportWS.Cells(i + 1, FindColumn.Column).Value
>
>  Next i
>
>  Next Column
> End If
>
> Next
> End Sub
> ```

**Note:**I have moved the code to the module than the workbook code behind.

Happy to explain, if more info is required. Thank you All.

Regards,

Mani

Answer (score 0):

You don't deserve a sub from scratch, made no uniformization or efforts otherwise to get anywhere.
Since you're apparently not intending to learn either I didn't really bother commenting the code. If I'm wrong and you would like to learn what these lines are doing feel free to comment under and I'll respond.

```
Sub ertdfgcvb()
ExportWS = "Merged"
Dim ImportWS(1 To 3) As String
    ImportWS(1) = "Sheet1"
    ImportWS(2) = "sheet2"
    ImportWS(3) = "sheet3"
Dim TransCol(1 To 2) As String
    TransCol(1) = "Current Day Adjustment"
    TransCol(2) = "ISIN"
For i = 1 To 3 'for each import sheet
    FirstImportRow = Worksheets(ImportWS(i)).Cells.Find(TransCol(1), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row + 1
    LastImportRow = Worksheets(ImportWS(i)).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    DiffRows = LastImportRow - FirstImportRow
    FirstExportRow = Worksheets(ExportWS).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    ExportColumn = Worksheets(ExportWS).Cells.Find("Sheet Name", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column 'defines where to insert the sheet name
    Worksheets(ExportWS).Range(Cells(FirstExportRow, ExportColumn), Cells(FirstExportRow + DiffRows, ExportColumn)) = ImportWS(i)
    For j = 1 To 2 'for each column that has to be transported
        ExportColumn = Worksheets(ExportWS).Cells.Find(TransCol(j), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column 'defines where to insert the data
        ImportColumn = Worksheets(ImportWS(i)).Cells.Find(TransCol(j), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column 'defines where to insert the data from
        For k = 0 To DiffRows
            Worksheets(ExportWS).Cells(FirstExportRow + k, ExportColumn) = Worksheets(ImportWS(i)).Cells(FirstImportRow + k, ImportColumn)
        Next
    Next

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @user3819867.It was not a compiled or tested version i believe. Added the looping is too heavy.I have come up with simple concepts. But really appreciate your efforts and helping tendency.