# Detect cells range of any file in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I apologize if this is a stupid question but I can't get to figuring this one out.

What I want to do is import a .csv / .xlsx / .xls file and have a vba module auto-detect the range and do some cell formatting / apply filter etc. and eventually do a pivot.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You probably need **UsedRange**

Comment: Related: [How can I find the last row /or column/ that contains data in a specific column and on a specific sheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro).

Answer (score 0):

Gary's student is right.

```
Dim lRow as Long
Dim lCol as Long

lRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.count
lCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.count
```

Or

```
Dim r As Range
r = ws.UsedRange
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback