# VBA - excel insert value after last column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert a new column AFTER the last one that is populated. How can i find out which was the last column populated?.

e.g. i have the below headers :

```
Name , Date , Address
```

I want to insert `'test1','test2','test3'` after address. How is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find last row that contains data in the Excel sheet with a macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)

Comment: @Bulat, I believe Rory is looking to find the last column, not last row.

Comment: Yes, I picked the wrong question, questions on last column also exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes your headers are on the first row.

```
Dim x as Integer
x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, x+1) = "Test1"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, x+2) = "Test2"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, x+3) = "Test3"
```

I recommend adding code to test and make sure your last column header isn't "Test3" already (indicating that you are adding three extra columns that you don't need).

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cNext as Range

Set cNext = Activesheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)

cNext.resize(1, 3).value = Array("Name","Date","Address")
```