# Is it possible to select a range of data via a macro if the start and end row is variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add a piece of code to my macro that copies and pastes a range of data.

The problem that I am having is that the data can start and finish on any row.

Is it possible to do this?

e.g. Currently the data starts in cell C10 and ends in cell I20. But next month it could start in C5 and end in I40.

The column range will always remain the same i.e C:I, but the row will change each time.

How to a add code to search for the first instance of data in Column C and copy all the data that follows?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible, also pretty easy to do. Just put the first row and last row value in variables and enter the value manually when it as to be change. Please post a piece of code you tried so we can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find last row that contains data in the Excel sheet with a macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some code snippets that might help

Get the first cell in C

```
If Range("C1").Value <> "" Then
    Set firstcell = Range("C1")
Else
    Set firstcell = Range("C1").End(xlDown)
End If
```

I test C1 because it will go all the way to the bottom if that is the only cell in C with values.

After that, to get the bottom cell after that

```
Set lastcell = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)
```

Comment: It sounds like this would work but I don't know how to then copy the range. Would you be able to help me do that? Thanks

Comment: Yes. You just need something like

 Range(firstcell,lastcell).Copy destinationrange

Answer (score 0):

Another way might be to use a named range in the spreadsheet to define the range you want to copy.

```
=OFFSET(C1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(NOT(ISBLANK(C:C)),0),0)-1,0,COUNTA(C:C),7)
```

That formula will select any number of data rows starting anywhere in column `C`.  It doesn't account for header rows or any other content.  If your data would always start in at least, say, row 5, then you could adjust the `C1` value and use `C5:C1000` instead of `C:C`.  Then, in the VBA you can just use `Range("namedRange")`. Copy instead of having to work out the start and end points.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like you're getting data incoming from somewhere, so you're not going to want to go and create a named range every time, so maybe this isn't much use.  Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

If you highlight the required cells before running the macro, then you can use
    Selection
to refer to the selected range

ie, instead of

```
 Range("C10:i20").Clear
```

you can write

```
Selection.Clear
```