# Copy and Paste Cell into row below VBA Loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to create VBA code that copies and pastes data from Column B into the row directly beneath in Column A.  I do not have great experience with VBA and so I am struggling to create such a code.

I would like to create a code that loops for an entire set of data in Columns A and B as shown in the attached picture.[image]

So for example, B3 would get pasted into A4.  B5 would get pasted into A6. And all the way down until the list was completed.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: you could write in C3 `=A3` and in C4 `=B3`. Then simply copy down and you got the list you desitre (simply copy/paste(values only) to the range at column A at the end)

Comment: Or simply: `Sub test(): Dim i As Long: i = 3: While Len(Cells(i, 1)): Cells(i + 1, 1) = Cells(i, 2): i = i + 2: Wend: End Sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works quite good for your criteria.

```
rowNum = 3
Do While Trim(Range("A" & rowNum).Value) <> ""
   Range("A" & (rowNum + 1)).Value = Range("B" & rowNum).Value
   rowNum = rowNum + 2
Loop
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that will do what you ask.

```
For i = 2 To 10
If Range("A" & i) > "" And Range("A" & i + 1) = "" Then
    Range("B" & i).Cut
    Range("A" & i + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Else
    End If
Next
```

Depending on what your data looks like, you will probably want to setup something more dynamic for the value of 'i'.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LastRowIndex` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71296/42346 to find the final row then iterate over the rows in column 2 placing the value in column 1 one row below the current row.

```
Sub iterate()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim endrow As Long

    c = 2
    endrow = LastRowIndex(ActiveSheet, c)
    For r = 2 To endrow Step 1
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c).Value <> "" Then
             ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 1, c - 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c).Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub

Function LastRowIndex(ByVal w As Worksheet, ByVal col As Variant) As Long
  Dim r As Range

  Set r = Application.Intersect(w.UsedRange, w.Columns(col))
  If Not r Is Nothing Then
    Set r = r.Cells(r.Cells.Count)

    If IsEmpty(r.Value) Then
      LastRowIndex = r.End(xlUp).Row
    Else
      LastRowIndex = r.Row
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you!