# How do I find the last row that contains data where cells may contain empty text ""?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the last row of a column.

Every cell in the column has the formula `=IF(ISERROR(AVERAGE(F5:G5));"";AVERAGE(F5:G5))`

I am using the below VBA code to find the last row.

```
lastrow= Worksheets("SPONSOR ENGAGEMENT").Cells(Worksheets("SPONSOR ENGAGEMENT").Rows.Count, trendcnt).End(xlUp).Row
```

However that code also counts cells which have empty text "" resulting from the formula.

How can I count only the cells which have data not empty text?

Comment: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro should be of help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: Hi Ralph & Scott, thanks for helping me out with those links. I tried this code but it gives me exactly the same result. lastline = Worksheets("SPONSOR ENGAGEMENT").Columns(TRENDC).Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row it still counts the empty text ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used Gary's first code and made it fast:

```
Function LastRowWithNonNullData() as Long
Dim LastRow As Variant
Dim i As Long
LastRow = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).Value2
For i = Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If LastRow(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then
            'MsgBox i
            LastRowWithNonNullData = i
            Erase LastRow
            Exit Function
        End If
Next i
Erase LastRow
End Function
```

For example on my computer it takes 0,125 secondes (instead of 4,3 secondes) if i only put something in cell "A1".

I Also made it a function, more usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, but it is very slow:

```
Sub LastRowWithNonNullData()
    Dim LastRow As Variant, i As Long
        For i = Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" Then
                MsgBox i
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub
```

This is not quite as slow:

```
Sub IsThisAnyBetter()
    MsgBox Evaluate("IF(COUNTA(A:A)=0,"""",MAX((A:A<>"""")*(ROW(A:A))))")
End Sub
```

Both will ignore *Null*s at the bottom of column **A**.  If you use the argument to *Evaluate()* directly in a worksheet cell, it must be array-entered.

**EDIT#1:**

Both subs work on column **A**.  Say we want to modify the formula in the second sub to work on column **77** (that is column **BY**).  Here is a way to do it:

```
Sub AnyColumn()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, iCol As Long, iColAlpha As String
    Dim s3 As String, s4 As String, s5 As String

    iCol = 77
    s1 = "IF(COUNTA(A:A)=0,"""",MAX((A:A<>"""")*(ROW(A:A))))"
    s2 = Cells(1, iCol).Address(0, 0)
    s3 = Left(s2, Len(s2) - 1)
    s4 = s3 & ":" & s3
    s5 = Replace(s1, "A:A", s4)

    MsgBox s5
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

The formula I used in *Evaluate()* was adapted from [Chip Perason](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ListFirstAndLastElements.aspx)

Comment: Hi Gary,this code seems to be working perfectly and fast. But i do have one more question. how can i pass a range like Cells(initc, trendcnt), Cells(Target, trendcnt)  where initc, trendcnt, target are variables?

Comment: @cube2016  You would need to splice together a new string for *Evaluate()* to process based on your parameters.

Comment: Hi Gary, I would be really grateful if you can provide a small example for your solution where I can use variables. example : I have to read the range A1:A2 but I want to provide it as range(cells(1,1),cells(1,2))

Comment: @cube2016  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Gary, Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Can you explain me what exactly the function does in Evaluate("IF(COUNTA(A:A)=0,"""",MAX((A:A<>"""")*(ROW(A:A))))") so that I can expand it for other stuff

Comment: @cube2016  See my **EDIT#2**