# Auto fill down cell in Excel VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

```
Sub AutoFill()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastcolumn As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For x = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(x, 2).Value = "" Then
            Cells(x, 2).Value = Cells(x - 1, 2).Value
            Cells(x, 3).Value = Cells(x - 1, 3).Value
            Cells(x, 5).Value = Cells(x - 1, 5).Value
        End If
    Next x

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

With the above code My cells are being filled up, but the last row fills till the end of excel sheet. In the Excel sheet column `D` is already filled in Column `B` `C` & `E` should be auto fill to down. What should be the changes in the code?

Comment: why  ` ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` ??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro

Comment: Your code is working as per your requirement on my pc. [Check](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kg380esjoyxb0o9/autofill_sample.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: For lastRow, I'd instead compare your three columns, and get the last row from there. `UsedRange`, in my experience, doesn't always use the range I'd expect. `lastRow = Max(cells(rows.count,2).End(xlUp).Row,cells(rows.count,3).End(xlUp).Row,cells(rows.count,5).End(xlUp).Row`  *or* `LastRow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row`

Comment: yes, I have changed it to  LastRow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row  still there are some problems, in column E there are some parts are not filled in with the macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Excel VBA Last Row: The Complete Tutorial To Finding The Last Row In Excel With VBA (And Code Examples)](http://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-last-row/#vba-code-to-find-last-row-example-8rangefind-method) recommends using `LookIn:=xlFormulas` when determining the last with using `Cells.Find`.

```
lastrow = Find(What:=” * ”, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Because you stated that column D is already filled in I use:

```
lastrow = Range("D" &  Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

If column E isn't filled in then `Cells(x, 2).Value` must be `<> ""`.

```
Sub AutoFill()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastcolumn As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    lastrow = Range("D" &  Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastrow

        If Cells(x, 2).Value = "" Then Cells(x, 2).Value = Cells(x - 1, 2).Value
        If Cells(x, 3).Value = "" Then Cells(x, 3).Value = Cells(x - 1, 3).Value
        If Cells(x, 5).Value = "" Then Cells(x, 5).Value = Cells(x - 1, 4).Value

    Next x
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad that I  could help.