# Last row in column VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a short VBA code to automate stuff.
A short snippet is as follows:

```
Sub TEST()

    Rows("1:2").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$O$148"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table2"

End Sub
```

However, every Excel file differs with regards to the number of rows. Now when I recorded this macro it just takes the range of $A$1:$O$148. How can I adjust this part so that it automatically recognizes the last row and/or range?

I already tried:

```
.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

Instead of:

```
Range("$A$1:$O$148")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find last row that contains data in the Excel sheet with a macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)

Comment: NINJA'd You might find the page mentioned above interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way I do it and I'm guessing this is a duplicate, but you can mimic hitting `End-Up` from  a row well below your used range with

```
finalRow = Range("A65000").End(xlup).Row
```

then you can do

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$O$" & finalRow & ""), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table2"
```

Comment: This one was the easiest answer to follow and it worked, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome I believe there is value in understandable solutions. All the best in your future work.

Comment: Yes there is :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you can find the last row / column and therefore the complete used range by using:

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NAME").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row`

for the last row and

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NAME").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

for the last column.
I would advice against using `UsedRange` because if you have blanks in between, it will lead to mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UsedRange` property of your worksheet-object.
You can get the indexes of your last used row and column using

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

So you would basically use this like

```
With m_Sheet
  ' Use this range
  .Range(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the shortcut `Ctrl+Arrow Down`, which resulted in following VBA (after recording the macro):

```
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
Dim rSource As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set rSource = .Range("A1", .Columns("A:O").Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious))

End With
```

Answer (score 1):

This would help if you don't know much of the vba library or syntax like me.

```
Dim lastline as long
Dim lastColumnline as long
dim usedcells as long
dim i as long
dim YOURCOLUMN as long
dim count as long

Set ws = Worksheet("blablabla")
lastline = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
usedcells = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Columns(YOURCOLUMN))
for i = 1 to lastline
 if ws.cells(i,YOURCOLUMN) <> vbnullstring then
  count = count + 1
     if count = usedcells then
        lastColumnline  = i
        'i is the lastColumnline 
     end if
 end if
next i
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I locate last row:

```
Function lastRow(Optional strSheet As String, Optional column_to_check As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim shSheet As Worksheet

    If strSheet = vbNullString Then
        Set shSheet = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set shSheet = Worksheets(strSheet)
    End If

    lastRow = shSheet.Cells(shSheet.Rows.Count, column_to_check).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

The column is optional, if no value is given, it is column **A**.
My [GitHub repository with LastThings is here](https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/master/LastThings.vb).