# Clear content witha criteria and adjusting cells

Tags: vba, excel

[image]Im trying to construct a vba code which will clear content if cells = 0. However this depends on the previous vba code which changes the format of some cells. My code until now is:

Sub Macro1()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim lastRow As Variant

```
Range("A4:A65000").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B4"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("B4").Select

 Range("E4:F4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E4:F" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

 lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


  lastRow = lastRow + 1
  Rows(lastRow & ":F" & 2 ^ 20).ClearContents


  End Sub
```

So depending on the code i sometimes end up with a alot of cells containg "00" in row "G".

I thought i could use the code "Clearcontent", but im unsure to use it when the cells are adjusting all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Locate last row in the column `A`. [Last row in column VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470412/last-row-in-column-vba) Lets say it is row 250. Let's say it is `k`
2. Then write the following at the end:

---

```
k = k + 1
Rows(k & ":" & 2^20).ClearContents
```

Comment: But the last row in column A is changing all the time, depending on how many dates I insert.

Comment: @Skyrup - that's why you should locate it with a VBA function, every time after you make an update - check the link in my answer.

Comment: Im just using a regular code like this to find it:                                    Range("A65536").End(xlup).Select.

Comment: What if you have data in cell A65537? You should find the last row programatically.

Comment: Try this to find the last row in column A `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Allright, I see that would be a good idea. However im unsure how to write the code which will delete the data in Row "G" up to the last row in "A" which I have just found.

Comment: Try with the two lines in my answer, @Skyrup

Comment: lastRow = lastRow + 1
Rows(lastRow & ":" & 2 ^ 20).ClearContents. I am very sorry that im unable to understand, but what does " 2^20" do for the code?

Comment: `2^20` is `1048576`, e.g. the last row in Excel since Excel 2010, @Skyrup

Comment: I get the error "missmatch". I have updated my question with my new code.

Comment: @Skyrup - try this -   `Rows(lastRow & ":" & 2 ^ 20).ClearContents`

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what im looking for. Thank you so much, and its so much quicker than constructing a loop which was my alternative.

Comment: @Skyrup - congrats! :)