# Date Stamp whenever someone refreshes the table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, refresh

I have a pivot table in my Sheet1 connected to external sources which is also an excel sheet. All i am trying to do is to get a date and time stamp whenever someone refreshes pivot table.

I get an error Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
Private Sub Refresh_Click()
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim WS As Worksheet
  For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
  PT.RefreshTable
  WS.Sheets("Month-to-Date").Range("P5") = TimeValue(Now)
  Next PT
  Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: Try: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Month-to-Date").Range("P5") = TimeValue(Now)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: Just something to think about.  What happens if someone changes the name of the worksheet "Month-to-Date" to something else by accident, or on purpose.  Wouldnt that throw the entire code off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `WS` is a Worksheet and a Worksheet does not support another Worksheet as a property.

Worksheets are properties of Work*books* so

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Month-to-Date").Range("P5") = TimeValue(Now)
```

Fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a fancy built-in event in Excel VBA for this. In the worksheet of the pivot table, select the event `PivotTableUpdate` ([Event Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pivottableupdate)):

[image]

As far as probably there would be more than 1 pivot tables on the worksheet, it is a good idea to check which one is the refreshed one, using its name:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    Select Case Target.Name

    Case "PivotTable2"
        Debug.Print "Write date somewhere "; Format(Now, "DD-MM-YYYY")
    Case Else
        Debug.Print "Not PivotTable2"
    End Select        

End Sub
```

"DateStamp" is obtained through `Format(Now, "DD-MM-YYYY")` and printed to the immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). Instead of printing there, it is a possible option to write it to a server or to a separate worksheet, [getting the last cell of a row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47394801/5448626) like this:

```
Case "PivotTable2"
    Worksheets(2).Cells(lastCell, 1) = Format(Now, "DD-MM-YYYY")
```