# How to loop through a column adding values from a second column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in a table, let's say a and b. The value of the cells in a, when the macro is implemented, will be a = a + b. After the addition is performed, all the values in column b will be set to 0.

I've tried using a for loop to loop through every cell in the columns and adding the values but nothing happens.

```
Sub zeroAndAdd0_Click()

    For i = 2 To NumRows
        Cells(i, 4).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(i, 4).Value, Cells(i,5).Value)
    Next i    

End Sub
```

No error message occurs but nothing actually happens when I test it.

Comment: What is `NumRows`?

Comment: Right before the `For` loop, set your `NumRows` variable (currently it's not set so your loop isn't looping anything). `NumRows = 10`. Then you should see some magic happening. I just guessed at `10` though so you'll need to set that to whatever makes sense for your sheet. Once that is working then you may want to figure out how to [dynamically set `NumRows` to the last occupied row in one of these columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470412/last-row-in-column-vba).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you always write `Option Explicit` on the top of the module. Thus, it will make sure that all the variables in the code are declared. In the code above it was not entering the loop, because `NumRows` was undeclared, thus with a value of `0`. Try this instead:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 10
        With Worksheets(1)
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells(i, 4).Value, .Cells(i, 5).Value)
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub zeroAndAdd0_Click()

    Dim NumRows As Long

    'Change Sheet name
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'NumRows take tha value of a fix number
        NumRows = 10
        'NumRows take the value of Column D last row
        NumRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(NumRows, 4)).Formula = "=Sum(D2,E2)"

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think NumRows is populated, if the code is completely as in your question

Try

```
Sub zeroAndAdd0_Click()
Dim i As Long, NumRows As Long, csum As Double
Dim c As Range

With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF)
    NumRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row 'last row in Col D
    'For each is faster than For i when looping through a range
    For Each c In Range("D2:D" & NumRows) 
        csum = c.Value + c.Offset(,1).Value 'Populate a variable with the sum of the two cells
        c.Value = csum 'Populate the cell in col D with the sum
        c.Offset(,1).Value = 0 'Set the other cell to 0
    Next c
End With

End Sub
```

Info in the commented out code

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Sub zeroAndAdd0_Click()

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

        Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value + Cells(i, 5).Value
        Cells(i, 5).Value = 0

    Next i

End Sub
```

It will do both of the job for you. no need to use `Worksheet Function`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define your NumRows variable (i.e. NumRows = Sheet1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), then finish off with converting the values in column E to 0. So something like:

```
Sub zeroAndAdd0_Click()

    Dim NumRows, i As Long
    NumRows = Sheet1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To NumRows
        Cells(i, 4).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(i, 4).Value, Cells(i, 5).Value)
        Cells(i, 5).Value = 0
    Next i

End Sub
```