# Excel Validation Drop Down length issue in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA. I am having a VBA excel macro coding(Excel Validation Drop Down list using VBA) in a old project. When the drop-down going
to a maximum number of list I am getting the error.The drop down data are collected from another sheet

Below is the screenshot

[image]

[image]

```
Public Sub CORE_SetValidation(ByRef Rng As Range, ByVal Value As String)
    With Rng.Validation
        Call .Delete
        If Value <> "" Then
            Call .Add(Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Value)
            .ErrorMessage = "Please select a value from drop-down list"
            .ErrorTitle = "Value Error"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputMessage = ""
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

1. Is there any limit for characters or drop-down list in VBA drop-down, Because from the error message I am unable to predict the issue.
2. Can I able to get the exact error message.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code as text to make it part of your question.

Comment: @RichHolton I have added my coding

Comment: syntax note: `Call` is deprecated and unnecessary. Just use `.Delete` and `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a string that contains the list of validation values separated by commas, use a string that specifies a range where the list is stored. For example, if you validation list is stored on the worksheet "ValidationValues" in column A from row 2 to 1001, your string would look like this:

```
"=ValidationValues!A2:A1001"
```

Each validation value needs to be in its own worksheet cell.

You could then pass this string in to the CORE_SetValidation sub:

```
Call CORE_SetValidation(myRange, "=ValidationValues!A2:A1001")
```

Comment: Can I get the total rows value dynamically from the sheet "ValidationValues" to form the above validation

Comment: Yes, in various ways. See for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro

Comment: Great; Your Answer and comments gives me the good solution for me. But after saving the file I am closing it. Then when I reopen the saved file it gives this error **"File error:data may have been lost."**

Comment: I'm sorry that you're having this problem. I don't know what would cause it. Are you able to tell what data was lost? Maybe you should open a new question so others can help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, One last question can I apply sorting to the created drop down using the range