# Type Mismatch Error VBA: Array referencing named ranges in Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

### **SCOPE**

Code below is attempting to grab all table objects, chart objects and range names on my workbook as an array, then the code creates a data validation column on a table which these arrays can then be referenced--so later I can use this table to auto generate a PowerPoint presentation.

### **PROBLEM**

Code for grabbing tables and charts works great--getting type mismatch error when developing the portion of code for named ranges **(please see further down for entire block of code/variables)**:

```
 'if we have named ranges'
    If ThisWorkbook.Names.Count > 0 Then
    
        'grab each range
        **For Each ExcRng In ThisWorkbook.Names**  **'PROBLEM OCCURS HERE'**
        
            'update count
            ObjectArrayIndex = ObjectArrayIndex + 1
            ReDim Preserve ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex)
            
                'add the named range to array
                ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex) = ExcRng.Name & "-" & xlSheet.Name & "-" & TypeName(ExcRng)
```

### **CODE**

```
Sub GetTablesAndChartToExportTable()

    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim xlTable As ListObject
    Dim xlTableColumn As ListColumn
    Dim xlChartObject As ChartObject
    Dim xlTableObject As ListObject
    
    Dim ObjectArray() As String
    Dim ObjectIndexArray As Integer
    
    Dim ExcRng As Range
    
    'set the book
    Set xlBook = ThisWorkbook
    
    'loop through each worksheet
    For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets
    
        'if we have charts
        If xlSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        
            'grab each chart name
            For Each xlChartObject In xlSheet.ChartObjects
            
                'update count
                ObjectArrayIndex = ObjectArrayIndex + 1
                ReDim Preserve ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex)
                
                    'add the chart object to array
                    ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex) = xlChartObject.Name & "-" & xlSheet.Name & "-" & TypeName(xlChartObject)
                
                
            Next
        End If
        
        'if we have tables
        If xlSheet.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
        
            'grab each table name
            For Each xlTableObject In xlSheet.ListObjects
            
                'update count
                ObjectArrayIndex = ObjectArrayIndex + 1
                ReDim Preserve ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex)
                
                    'add the table object to array
                    ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex) = xlTableObject.Name & "-" & xlSheet.Name & "-" & TypeName(xlTableObject)
                
                
            
            Next
        End If
        
        'if we have named ranges'
        If ThisWorkbook.Names.Count > 0 Then
        
            'grab each range
            For Each ExcRng In ThisWorkbook.Names
            
                'update count
                ObjectArrayIndex = ObjectArrayIndex + 1
                ReDim Preserve ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex)
                
                    'add the named range to array
                    ObjectArray(ObjectArrayIndex) = ExcRng.Name & "-" & xlSheet.Name & "-" & TypeName(ExcRng)
                    
        
        Next
      End If
    Next
    
    'grab sheet
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Export")
        
        'grab table from sheet
        Set xlTable = xlSheet.ListObjects("ExportToPowerPoint")
        
            'grab object column from table
            Set xlTableColumn = xlTable.ListColumns("Object")
            
                'set the validation dropdown
                With xlTableColumn.DataBodyRange.Validation
                
                    'delete old
                    .Delete
                    
                    'add new data
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(ObjectArray, ",")
                    
                    'make sure it's a dropdown
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    
                End With
            
    End Sub
```

### **NOTICE**

I am by no means very experienced in VBA, please, in your answer, include as much detail as possible

Comment: Please don't make us work out which line errors.

Comment: @SJR the problem code is shown above...clearly labeled under the bold title "problem." Thanks

Comment: @Vityata For Each ExcRng In ThisWorkbook.Names -- I wrote next to it

Comment: Try `Dim ExcRng As Variant` instead of `Dim ExcRng As Range`

Comment: `Dim ExcRng As Name`

Comment: @chrisneilsen So no longer an issue at above mentioned line, now its application defined/object defined error at line " .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(ObjectArray, ",") " further on down the block of code

Comment: Cool! Try to rewrite the code in a separate question, using as few lines as possible in order to replicate the error. Really, instead of 20+, try only validation and the assignment of the `ObjectArray`. The code should be able to compile. Good luck!

Comment: `Join(ObjectArray, ",")` does not add leading or trailing `"` to the joined string.  You'll need to add those

Comment: You can move the Name-related code outside of the `For Each xlSheet` loop

Comment: @chrisneilsen not sure I follow, I am not familiar really with syntax

Answer (score 1):

The `For Each ExcRng In ThisWorkbook.Names` is iterating through the collection `ThisWorkbook.Names`. Thus, the `ExcRng` should be of type `Name`.

To stay on the sure site, whenever iterating with `For Each [x] In [y]`, declare the `[x]` as a `variant`. This will make sure it works, but it will take away intellisense and will be a bit "heavier".

Comment: Names is a collection of Name objects.  (Edited to correct)

Comment: Cool! This got the block for named ranges to go through which is good. Now weirdly it caused an application defined / object defined error later on in my code which I find odd... If only Microsofts error messages could be better detailed lol

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450523/excel-validation-drop-down-length-issue-in-vba