# VBA; what it means, when there are arguments in the brackets after the subroutine title?

Tags: vba, excel

I've written about 10 easy macros in the last 18 months, and I would like to understand more than I do in VBA programming.

In none of the subroutines I've written were there arguments in the brackets after the subroutine title.

I have found this code ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)) on stackoverflow.
It's used to find the last row that contains data in the Excel sheet.
But it's got some arguments/parameters (please explain the difference) in the brackets after the subroutine name, which I've never seen before.

What do these arguments stand for? I'm unable to figure this out.

```
Sub GetLastRow(strSheet, strColumn)
     Dim MyRange As Range
     Dim lngLastRow As Long

     Set MyRange = Worksheets(strSheet).Range(strColum & "1")

     lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, MyRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Another thing I don't understand is why the "MyRange" variable needed to be created. 
Was this necessary or is there a way to simplify this code, get rid of "MyRange" variable and use `Worksheets("MBank_Statsy").UsedRange` property??

Below you can see the worksheet that I would like to apply this code to.

[image]

Comment: Google: vba arguments vs parameters

Comment: MyRange was not needed it just makes it ugly. theres no reason to have a string for the column number. also it has to be `Sub Test(Var1 as Integer)`and not just the var name.

Comment: Which argument you have a question about? There are 2 parameters and 5 arguments used in your code snippet... which is the one you have trouble understanding?

Comment: For arguments [see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527(v=vs.60).aspx).  As you say MyRange is not required, you could skip it.  The author probably did it that way as its cheap to use a variable and makes the code more readable.  If the code made use of the range more than once you should always use a variable as there is a small cost when accessing sheets & ranges by name/address as a lookup is involved.

Comment: @trincot I don't understand 'Sub GetLastRow(strSheet, strColumn)' why there are parameters in the sub brackets.
I was writing an excel function once, and after it's name I've put some parameters in the brackets, but I don't understand why to put parameters into subroutine brackets.

Comment: The Sub (which, to make it of any real use should really be a Function) is basically a routine that finds the LastRow for a given Sheet and Column. The author has chosen to provide these as strings (rather than the objects themselves). If the Sheet and Column weren't provided, the routine would not know which Sheet and Column you wanted the result for.

Comment: Parameters are passed to a Sub in exactly the same way, and for exactly the same reason as when passing them to a Function : to provide context on which to perform the routine. The only real difference is that a Function is expected to return a value, a Sub is just expected to 'do' things..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comments upon your question have probably given you all the info you need on why things are done the way they are, but if you're interested, the entire subroutine could be reduced to:

```
Function GetLastRow(strSheet, strColumn)
     GetLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Worksheets(strSheet).Range(strColumn & "1").Column).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Note: this is now a function. To find out the last used cell in Sheet1, column 'C' for instance, you would do something like this:

```
lastrowused = GetLastRow("Sheet1","C")
```

I suspect that the original routine started out with more going on (perhaps it found the last cell and did something to it) and has been stripped down to just retrieving the last row but no thought was given to reducing unnecessary instructions.

Comment: You can also simplify things to `GetLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, strColumn).End(xlUp).Row` because `Worksheets(strSheet).Range(strColumn & "1").Column` is just going to return the column that is already referred to by `strColumn`.