# Copy and paste to the last populated row

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to combine two sheets of data which are updated periodically and then remove duplicates.

I have 4 worksheets:

- Sheet X
- Sheet Y
- Sheet Z
- Sheet AA

Sheet X and Y are updated hourly and only ever grow.

I wish to clear `Sheet Z` completely, clear columns `C:P` on `Sheet AA`, Then copy all the data from `X` and `Y` and paste into `Z`, sort by `column A`, oldest to newest, then remove duplicates from `columns B & E`. Then copy all the data left and paste into `Sheet AA` where I run further calculations and `VLOOKUPS` from.

The issue I have is at the moment I am only copying/editing data up to the row which is recorded in the macro. Is there a way in which to select up to the last populated Row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find last row that contains data in the Excel sheet with a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take a few minutes to check out the [tour] as well as [ask] and [mcve].  You can [edit] your question to provide more specific information about your issue, starting with some examples showing what you have and what you need to do.