# Copy last row of sheet 1 down to amount of rows on sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the last row of sheet 1 which changes everytime, down the amount of rows on sheet2. I have formulas in the last row of sheet1 and would like them carried down.

Below is my code where I select the last row to copy but I cant get it to go down the amount of rows on sheet2.

I need to copy the last row (which a macro puts formulas in) on sheet1. Then I need to copy that last row down the amount of rows on sheet2. Sheet2 data is from A2 to last row of sheet2.

```
Sheets("2018").Activate

Dim nRow As Long, nColumn As Long

nRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

nColumn = Cells(nRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Range(Cells(nRow, "A"), Cells(nRow, nColumn)).Select

Set lastrow = Range(Cells(nRow, "A"), Cells(nRow, nColumn))

bottomrow = Sheets("Needs_Assignment").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range(lastrow).AutoFill Destination:=Range(bottomrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Thank you

Comment: so in fact you need to find the last row so you can copy it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)

Comment: I found the last row and am able to copy it my problem is getting it to copy down to the last row based on sheet 2 last row

Comment: The related question that was posted above isn't related. My range starts at the last row of sheet 1 and not a specified range ie A2:K and bottomrow

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in a recent project (copies formulas in row 1 for columns B to ZZ), so would expect a very similar pattern to work for your scenario:

```
     Dim wrkMyWorkBook As Workbook
     'Set wrkMyWorkBook = ' Set this to a valid value 

     Dim LR As Long
     LR = wrkMyWorkBook.Sheets("Target Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
     wrkMyWorkBook.Sheets("Target Sheet").Range("B1:ZZ1").AutoFill Destination:=wrkMyWorkBook.Sheets("Target Sheet").Range("B1:ZZ" & LR)
```

Comment: I tried this but my issue is that my range changes every time I open the file. The formula is in the last row which changes rows.