# Copy cells from one sheet and paste in another to a variable cell

Tags: excel, vba

I copy cells (from sheet1) if they contain a specific value (got this part figured out).

I need to paste them in a cell on sheet2 in row j.

Sheet1 has a long list of names, companies, emails, phones etc. with each person's information separated by a space. For Ex:

```
Column A                       Column B
Smith, Jill                     #N/A
CEO                             #N/A
ABC Corp 123 street             ABC Corp
jill@ABC.com                    #N/A
                                #N/A
Smith, John                     #N/A
CTO                             #N/A
123 Inc ABC street              123 Inc
john@123.com                    #N/A
```

I have a variable (j) that counts each space and then if Cell b does not equal #NA, then cell a is copied and pasted into sheet2 column M and row j.
Variable j is needed because the formula in column B isn't 100% and the data is inconsistent so I need j so that the company name stays on the same line as the name. I need this because I have other code to split column A (like 4000 rows) into separate sheets by names, titles, companies, emails.

I.e. Sheet3 would have:
 1. Jill Smith
 2. John Smith

```
Sub AutoCompany()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lr As Long, tr As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

tr = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

'this is my formula for column B
Range("B2:B" & lr).Formula = "=INDEX(CompaniesTbl[CompanyNamesList],IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CompaniesTbl[CompanyNamesList],A2)))<>0,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CompaniesTbl[CompanyNamesList],A2))*ROW($1:$" & tr & ")),NA()))"
j = 0
k = 1

For i = 2 To lr Step 1
    'increase j by 1 if there is a blank space (to figure out where to paste)
    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        j = j + 1
        'extra  variable just cause
        k = k + 1
    End If
    'check for an actual value
    If Application.IsNA(Cells(i, 2)) Then
        Else
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Worksheets("Company").Activate
        Worksheets("Company").Range("M" & j).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    End If
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This causes an error

> "object defined or variable defined"

If I remove j from my paste selection, the error is gone but all my pastes are overwritten.

I can't remember what I had done before, but I basically didn't have all of the sheet activations and that caused a out of range error. Which I fix by activating a sheet, but that causes my variable to cause an error.

Edit:
Based on the comments and answer, the issue is not in how the VBA is written per se. I think it has to do with the fact that the variable j is unable to be called in the if statement. I can't figure another way to do this or how to troubleshoot that issue.

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) rename your variables with something readable. lr could be lastRow for example. 2) try to fully qualify when referring to ranges. Range("B2:B... would be Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B... the idea here is to be precise and know where data is coming from and going to. 3) Get rid of activate and select lines. Having done step 2. They’re not needed anymore. 4) when passing values from a cell to another you don’t need to use copy. Just worksheets("Company").Range("M" & j).value = worksheets("Sheet1").cells(i,2).value. 5) Run the macro step by step (line by line F8).

Comment: If a cell in column A is blank will the cell in column B same row be blank?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Thanks for the tips. I tried what you said but I still get an object defined error when it tries to set the value on the company worksheet. Running it line by line, it was fine until the first instance where my column B was not #NA

Comment: @GMalc Oversight in the question on my part. If column A is blank, B is #NA. Edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that tried helping. I found the problem.
My J variable was set to 0 and so the first time the code ran, it tried pasting to cell 0 which is out of scope of the worksheet. The reason why I had set my variable to 0 was because I assumed the first empty row that it finds (above the dataset) would set the variable to 1 but that was not the case. 
Anyways, I set J to 1 and it worked...
[D'oh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XJgo.png)

Answer (score 0):

From deciphering your code I assume that you what to copy the company names from column B to `Worksheets("Company")` column M, starting on the first row.

```
Dim cel As Range, j As Long 'assign your variables

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'use "With" so you don't have to activate your worksheets
    j = 1
        For Each cel In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) 'loop through each cell in range
            If Application.IsNA(cel) Then 'test for error and skip

            ElseIf cel.Value = "" Then 'test for blank cell and skip

            'It is better to set a cells value equal to another cells value then using copy/paste.
            Else: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Company").Cells(j, "M").Value = cel.Value

            j = j + 1 'add 1 to j to paste on the next row

            End If
        Next cel
    End With
```

Comment: So this does not error out on me, but I need J to increase when Column A has a blank and only then, because my data is stupid inconsistent, so sometimes a person will have the company name written twice, and some will have none.

Comment: Just tested this with a variable that increase when the elseif runs and I get the same object defined error

Answer (score 0):

Check my code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

```
Option Explicit ' -> Always use this at the top of your modules and classes

' Define your procedures as public or private
' Indent your code (I use RubberDuck (http://rubberduckvba.com/) which is a great piece of software!
Public Sub AutoCompany()

    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False           ' This should be used with an error handler see https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/tag/error-handling/

    ' Declare object variables
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lookupSheet As Worksheet
    Dim resultsSheet As Worksheet

    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim evalCell As Range

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim sourceSheetName As String
    Dim lookupSheetName As String
    Dim resultsSheetName As String
    Dim sourceLastRow As Long
    Dim lookupLastRow As Long

    ' Initialize variables
    sourceSheetName = "Sheet1"
    lookupSheetName = "Sheet2"
    resultsSheetName = "Company"

    ' Initialize objects
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sourceSheetName) ' This could be replaced by using the sheet's codename see https://www.spreadsheet1.com/vba-codenames.html
    Set lookupSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(lookupSheetName) ' Same as previous comment
    Set resultsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(resultsSheetName) ' Same as previous comment

    ' Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate -> Not needed

    sourceLastRow = sourceSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' This is unreliable -> see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49971492/1521579
    lookupLastRow = lookupSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1 ' Couldn't understand why you subtract 1

    ' Define the sourceRange so we can loop through the cells
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A2:A" & sourceLastRow)

    ' this is my formula for column B -> Comments should tell why you do something not what you're doing
    sourceSheet.Range("B2:B" & sourceLastRow).Formula = "=INDEX(CompaniesTbl[CompanyNamesList],IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CompaniesTbl[CompanyNamesList],A2)))<>0,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CompaniesTbl[CompanyNamesList],A2))*ROW($1:$" & lookupLastRow & ")),NA()))"


    ' Begin the loop to search for matching results
    For Each evalCell In sourceRange

        ' Skip cells that are empty
        If evalCell.Value <> vbNullString Then

            ' Check value in column B (offset = 1 refers to one column after current cell and using not before application.IsNA checks for is found)
            If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(evalCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Value) Then

                ' We use current evaluated cell row in the results sheet
                resultsSheet.Range("M" & evalCell.Row).Value = evalCell.Value

            End If

        End If

    Next evalCell

CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    Debug.Print "Catched an err: " & Err.Description & " ... do something!"
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works and remember to mark the answer if it does

Comment: Sorry I didn't get a chance to look at this til now, but this does not do what I need. It works to copy/paste but it does not paste to the specific cell I need it to. I need to past based on the number of blank spaces in column A before it is reached.