# Select used rows within a Named Range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Named Range called `Schd_Preview` which consists of cells `F3:K500`. Sometimes only 2 or 3 rows are used, sometimes 200 rows are used, sometimes all the rows are used.  How do I copy only used rows within `Schd_Preview` within VBA?

Edit: I have data to the left of `Schd_Preview` in range B2:C12.  `Intersect()` will not work with `.UsedRange` since it will include, at the very minimum, row 12 even if the named range only uses 2 rows.

Comment: Use `Intersect()`

Comment: Or make it a dynamic named range (vertically) and continue with same name. Assumes used rows contiguous.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I have data to the left of the named range which goes up to row 12.  Using `Intersect()` will result in including at least up to row 12 even if I am only using 2 rows in `Schd_Preview`.

Comment: If you have blanks cells around `Schd_Preview`, then `Range("Schd_Preview").CurrentRegion`. If you don't have blank cells around `Schd_Preview`, then https://stackoverflow.com/q/71180/11683.

Answer (score 0):

### Used Rows Within Range

- `NonCont` and `Cont` refer to the used rows i.e. are they contiguous.
- The first solution will not work if you have hidden used rows.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub NonCont1() ' Values, formulas, formats.
    Const PasteCell As String = "M3"
    With Range(PasteCell)
       .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, _
               Range("Schd_Preview").Columns.Count).Clear
    End With
    Dim rng As Range ' Copy Range
    Set rng = Range("Schd_Preview").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rng.Copy Range(PasteCell) ' If you need values, then use 'PasteSpecial'.
'    rng.Copy
'    Range(PasteCell).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Sub NonCont2() ' Values only.
    Const PasteCell As String = "M3"
    Const LastRowCol As Long = 1 ' in your case 1-6 (F-K).
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = Range("Schd_Preview").Value
    Dim UB2 As Long
    UB2 = UBound(Data, 2)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Data(i, LastRowCol) <> "" Then
            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To UB2
                Data(k, j) = Data(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    With Range(PasteCell)
       .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, UB2).Clear
       Dim rng As Range ' Paste Range
       Set rng = .Resize(k, UB2)
    End With
    rng.Value = Data
End Sub

' Surrounded by empty rows and columns.
Sub cont1()
    Const PasteCell As String = "M3"
    With Range(PasteCell)
       .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, _
               Range("Schd_Preview").Columns.Count).Clear
    End With
    Dim rng As Range ' Copy Range
    Set rng = Range("Schd_Preview").Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    rng.Copy Range(PasteCell) ' Values, formulas, formats.
    'Range(PasteCell).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value _
      = rng.Value ' Values only.
End Sub

' Empty column to the right, and empty row at the bottom.
Sub cont2()
    Const PasteCell As String = "M3"
    With Range(PasteCell)
       .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, _
               Range("Schd_Preview").Columns.Count).Clear
    End With
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = Range("Schd_Preview").Cells(1)
    Dim rng As Range ' Copy Range
    Set rng = Range("Schd_Preview").Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    With rng
        Set rng = .Resize(.Rows.Count + .Row - cel.Row, _
                          .Columns.Count + .Column - cel.Column) _
                  .Offset(cel.Row - .Row, cel.Column - .Column)
    End With
    rng.Copy Range(PasteCell) ' Values, formulas, formats.
    'Range(PasteCell).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value _
      = rng.Value ' Values only.
End Sub

Sub cont3() ' Values only. It's a simplified 'NonCont2'.
    Const PasteCell As String = "M3"
    Const LastRowCol As Long = 1 ' in your case 1-6 (F-K).
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = Range("Schd_Preview").Value
    Dim UB2 As Long
    UB2 = UBound(Data, 2)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Data(i, LastRowCol) = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    With Range(PasteCell)
       .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, UB2).Clear
       Dim rng As Range ' Paste Range
       Set rng = .Resize(i - 1, UB2)
    End With
    rng.Value = Data
End Sub
```