Find next empty row on separate sheet to transpose data
I need to copy data from one sheet (Saudi) only copying 1 particular column (D) and transpose that data (keeping the values in there) to another sheet (Results) to the next available row.
I have figured out how to transpose to the next sheet but cant get it to find the next line to use.
Data to copy
Transpose to next line
Code

Please don't post code as a picture, include the code as text in a question. You may a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-a-specific-column

Please, try the next way. Selecting sheets, ranges only wastes Excel resources and slow down the code:
Sub copyAndTransposeColumn()
  Dim wsS As Worksheet, lastR As Long, wsRes As Worksheet, lastRRes As Long
  
  Set wsS = Worksheets("Saudi") 'ActiveSheet 
  lastR = wsS.Range("D" & wsS.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in column D:D
  
  Set wsRes = Worksheets("Results")
  lastRRes = wsRes.Range("A" & wsRes.rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1 'first empty row on A:A
  
  'if you need to also copy format (it looks not being your case):
  'wsS.Range("D1:D" & lastR).Copy
  'wsRes.Range("A" & lastRRes).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, True
  
  'since you need only to copy/transpose values, this way is faster,  also not involving Clipboard:
  With wsS.Range("D1:D" & lastR)
     wsRes.Range("A" & lastRRes).Resize(, .rows.count).value = Application.Transpose(.value)
  End With
End Sub

Transpose has some limitations, but it will work well for the range you show. If you intend to use it on much larger ranges I can show you different methods of transposing...
