Loop all sheets and hyperlnk them, starting next sheet according to the next empty cell in another column
I have an "Index" page where I'm trying to loop through each sheet (except "Index" sheet) and

List the sheet
Hyperlink the sheet
List all the activites in the sheet

However, I want the next sheet name to be shown at the next empty cell according to another column. For example in the below, "Sheet2" should start at the row after Act3 of Sheet1.
Sheet     Activities
Sheet1    Act1
          Act2
          Act3
Sheet2    Act1
          Act2
Sheet3    Act1
          Act2

I am able to list and hyperlink the sheets as below:
Sub GetHyperlinks()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 2

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Index" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Index").Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Index").Cells(i, 1), _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'" & ws.Name & "'!A1", _
            TextToDisplay:=ws.Name

            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

I am also able to list the activites and get to the next correct cell if I run the 2 blocks of codes separately.
Sub FilterSheet()
    Range("B10:B100").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Index").Select
    Range("D3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
    Range("A2:E545").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$E$37").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="="
    Rows("4:47").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("D17").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$E$14").AutoFilter Field:=4
    
    NextFree = Range("D2:D" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
    Range("D" & NextFree).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Select

End Sub

But how do I combine the 2 blocks together, ie, how do I get the next sheet's name to start in the row after the last "Activities" column?
Thanks.

You may have a look onto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-a-specific-column

You need to determine the next 'sheet-column' row using the Activities column possibly implementing a counter for the activities. Please share the code that adds the activities (I guess somewhere inside the loop) so we can be of help. BTW, replace each occurrence of ActiveWorkbook with ThisWorkbook.

My apologies. I've added the list Activities part, which is just filtering of non-empty cells in a column, then copy and paste into the "Index" sheet. I get what I want if I were to run the 2 blocks of codes separately, but I have no idea how to combine them.

Please explain what these many conflicting references represent. Your sample data and the first code indicate copying the activities to cell B2 yet the second code copies to cell D3. Maybe share the screenshot of one of the filter sheets and accurately explain what must be copied where to.

Create an Index Sheet Including Values from a Column


Carefully study the screenshot and accordingly adjust the values in the constants section e.g. your 2nd code would suggest that DST_ACTIVITIES_COLUMN is "D".

Option Explicit ' at the top of the module

Sub UpdateIndexSheet()
    
    ' Define constants.
    ' Source ('filter')
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B2"
    ' Destination ('index')
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Index"
    Const DST_FIRST_DATA_ROW As Long = 2
    Const DST_HYPERLINK_COLUMN As String = "A"
    Const DST_ACTIVITIES_COLUMN As String = "B"
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the destination ('Index') sheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    
    ' Clear existing data (in this case, 'A2:XFD1048576').
    With dws.Cells(DST_FIRST_DATA_ROW, "A")
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, dws.Columns.Count - .Column + 1) _
            .Clear
    End With
    
    ' Determine the starting row - 1 for the variable to hold
    ' the current row after entering the 'If' statement 'dRow = dRow + 1'
    ' and after exitting the loop 'Next sws'.
    Dim dRow As Long: dRow = DST_FIRST_DATA_ROW - 1
    
    ' Loop through all the worksheets except the destination sheet,
    ' and for each sheet, add its name and hyperlink to the hyperlink column
    ' and add its activities to the activities column by using
    ' the 'AddActivities' procedure.
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        If sws.Name <> DST_SHEET_NAME Then
            dRow = dRow + 1
            dws.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=dws.Cells(dRow, DST_HYPERLINK_COLUMN), _
                Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="'" & sws.Name & "'!A1", _
                TextToDisplay:=sws.Name
            AddActivities _
                sws, SRC_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS, dws, dRow, DST_ACTIVITIES_COLUMN
        End If
    Next sws

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Index sheet updated.", vbInformation

End Sub

Sub AddActivities( _
        ByVal sws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal sFirstCellAddress As String, _
        ByVal dws As Worksheet, _
        ByRef dRow As Long, _
        ByVal dColumn As String)
    ' Note the 'ByRef' indicating that 'dRow' is also 'updated'
    ' in the calling procedure.
    
    ' Reference the source ('Filter') single-column range.
    Dim srg As Range, sRowsCount As Long
    With sws.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        sRowsCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If sRowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data in the source column
        Set srg = .Resize(sRowsCount)
    End With
    
    ' Loop through the cells of the source range and copy the first non-blank
    ' value to the current row of the destination activity column
    ' (the same as the sheet name) and each next to the next.
    Dim scell As Range, sValue As Variant, IsFirstAdded As Boolean
    For Each scell In srg.Cells
        sValue = scell.Value
        If Len(CStr(sValue)) > 0 Then ' is not blank
            If IsFirstAdded Then dRow = dRow + 1 Else IsFirstAdded = True
            dws.Cells(dRow, dColumn).Value = sValue
        End If
    Next scell

End Sub


Possible alternative without VBA (workbook still needs to be saved as macro-enabled due to the use of 'old' function):

to get sheet names, add a function sheetnames in Formulas > Name Manager


Then in Index sheet:

in A2 enter the following for hyperlinks and fill down as needed

=IF(ISBLANK(B2), "", HYPERLINK("#" & B2 & "!A1", B2))


in B1 enter the following to get sheets and activities

adjust A1:A100 to match your column containing activities



=LET(
    all_sheets, TRANSPOSE(TEXTAFTER(sheetnames, "]")),
    act_sheets, FILTER(all_sheets, all_sheets <> "Index"),
    REDUCE(
        {"Sheet", "Activities"},
        act_sheets,
        LAMBDA(acc, cur,
            LET(
                actitivies, IFERROR(
                    TOCOL(INDIRECT(INDEX(cur, 1, 1) & "!A1:a100"), 1),
                    ""
                ),
                sheet_, EXPAND(cur, ROWS(actitivies), , ""),
                VSTACK(acc, HSTACK(sheet_, actitivies))
            )
        )
    )
)

Here's the result of interim step:


hide column B, as the hyperlinks are in column A

Hyperlinks generated from dynamic array formula do not work as expected; that's why we need to use this workaround


After adding or removing worksheets, make a temporary change in the Index sheet to force a refresh

